# Mathematica for Computer Scientists

Tags: evaluation, reference-request, replacement

### Background

I've coded in C/Scheme for 10 years. I have a BS CS.

I've recently become very interested in pattern-matching (lisp's match macro), and term rewriting systems, which brought me to Mathematica.

I would like to read a book on Mathematica that will show me lots of cool term-rewriting as a programming style techniques.

### Question:

What should I read?

Comment: Gray's "Mastering Mathematica" has a nice chapter on rule-based programming followed by a discussion of substitution and Lambda calculus, so you may want to check that out.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I understand it's more narrow, but I thought the point of having such a big list of references is precisely to refer other questions there.

Comment: @CHM I agree with Leonid that it's not a duplicate (that's why I suggested to the OP to ask here when s/he originally asked on SO).  That's a good list, but it's *huge* and it's very difficult to dig out the few links that may be relevant for this question (if it were easy, I would have done it).  Note that the OP is not merely asking for books to learn Mathematica, the question is asking for references discussion a specific evaluation mechanism and programming style from a CS perspective.

Comment: **To the closers**: please think before you cast the close votes. This question is IMO well formulated, rather narrowly focused, and constructive. Please save us all the reopening effort.

Comment: I agree with @Leonid. I would not vote to close this and will vote to reopen if closed.

Comment: @Leonid I do not see the point of having huge resource lists if we are going to have also questions on parts of them. I don't think this should be closed (rather, I think the other question and answers are impossible to use, but that's another matter)

Comment: @Szabolcs (see comment above to Leonid)

Comment: @acl I agree with you that the long list of the other answer is pretty hard to use (although probably not impossible - some parts of it are smaller and logically separated from other parts). It may be that as we get more of such more narrow questions like this one, we will gradually outsource some of the links from that huge list to the answers to these questions, and then link from that list to these answers. In time, I hope that all this collection will become more usable.

Comment: @Leonid I should add here that I do appreciate the effort gone into compiling the other, long answer. I just wish it could be somehow made more usable (of course if parts of it resided in answers to other questions Faysal would have a hard time maintaining and adding it). I am not sure what the best solution is. I'll stop because, as is well-known, This Is Not A Discussion Forum :)

Comment: The [Pure](http://purelang.bitbucket.org) language is also based on term rewriting.  It's the only general purpose language that I know that uses this paradigm.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK, I will start with a few suggestions. I think, that what you really need is to *understand* Mathematica evaluator. Once you get this understanding, programming in Mathematica will become vastly easier for you, and you will be ready for the advanced examples showing the power of rules. So, here are the steps I'd take:

- Read the book of David Wagner,  ["Power programming with Mathematica, the kernel"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007912237X) (1996, Computing McGraw-Hill). This is the best book I know to explain the essence of Mathematica evaluation process, and it is full of nice examples. Although it is currently out of print, you can get a free, licensed PDF copy of the book [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/5).
- While Wagner explains many things about evaluation process, some more details can be found in the [WRI Technical Report](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4683) by David Withoff titled "Mathematica internals" (thanks @Faysal for reminding me about it). It is a short and very interesting read, and even though it was published in 1992, it is mostly accurate to these days (which speaks well of Mathematica design consistency).
- Get and read as many books by Roman Maeder as you can :-). There are four I know of, and I would read them in this order:

  - [Programming in Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020185449X)
  - [Computer science with Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521663954)
  - [Mathematica programmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124649904)
  - [Mathematica programmer II](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124649920)

  If you thoroughly read these, you will get more than enough background. They are not an easy read, but easily the best and most elegant exposition of Mathematica from the rule-based perspective, with plenty of non-trivial examples. I think his books are still unmatched, even though published way back. You should have no problems reading them after Wagner's book.
- After that, you can hunt for rule-based code in many places. There are many nice examples in the  [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942823) of  Michael Trott, and also  ["Mastering Mathematica"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122961056) by John Gray, as was mentioned in comments. There are also lots of good and non-trivial rule-based code in the past [MathGroup posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica), StackOverflow discussions ([[mathematica] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica)) and here on [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). I will try to collect links to some which I find representative and post them here in this answer.

But, to summarize: first, understand the evaluation sequence and evaluation control (Wagner's book is IMO the best source for that, and I will add some links to evaluation-related SO and SE threads here soon). After that, the rest will follow. With your Scheme background, it will be much easier, since the recursive part of Mathematica evaluator is   similar to what you know from Lisp / Scheme, so you will have to only grok the rule-based part (which is very substantial, and makes Mathematica evaluator really different).

Comment: Have you forgotten your own book? http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/ It's a gem and you know it :-)

Comment: @ndroock1 Thanks :). I did not focus on rule-based part, in fact I under-represented it. Neither did I focus on or explain the evaluation process. Both are covered in the new one I am working on, but who knows when it is ready (particularly with the current level of activity here which keeps me busy). Since the question was not about a collection of books on Mathematica programming, I did not include it then.

Comment: Wagner's book is available neither on amazon nor abebooks. How do I acquire a copy of said book?

Comment: Ask your university or city library.

Comment: About the evaluation process a brief description is given here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4683

Comment: @FaysalAberkane Yes, I was going to add that reference. This is the only place where the full evaluation sequence is described. Wagner also refers to this source, and so do I in  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534324/how-does-return-work/8534549#8534549). Will edit soon, thanks.

Comment: @Faysal: I like how that matheamtica's core fits in 12 pages. Reminds me of Scheme's meta circular evaluator.

Answer (score 4):

If you are relatively new to *Mathematica*, I would definitely pick up a copy of ["Programming with *Mathematica*: An Introduction"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107009464) by Paul Wellin. This will give you an excellent starting point and solid foundation before you progress to more advanced material. I am still working my way through Paul's book, but it has been well worth it and has really opened my eyes to the power of *Mathematica*.