# Internal Representation of ?name and ??name

Tags: syntax, information-function

### Code

```
FullForm[Hold[?name]]

Syntax::bktmcp: Expression "Hold[?name]]" has no closing "]".

Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

### Question

This is exercise 3.2 (page 47) of Power Programming w/ Mathematica

The task is:

"determine the internal representation of the expressions ?name and ??name"

The above is what I tried. It failed. How do I win?

Comment: @term-rewritica - you have Wagner's book? You lucky thing - mine was borrowed by someone years ago and never seen again.

Comment: @Verbeia: It's a most intense reading. Reminds me of the first time I read SICP.

Comment: @Verbeia I do have a copy of that one too (ironically, bought from Amazon fo $40 in 2004, when I just started learning Mathematica as a programming language - and I had no idea about the usefulness of the book at the time, it was a blind purchase). I was lucky to not give it to anyone (well, no one asked).

Comment: @term-rewritica Actually, Roman Maeder's books are more intense reading to me. I think, Wagner wrote his book on just the right level, for someone who knows some Mathematica and wants to bring their M skills to the next level. Can be a little hard to read for a complete beginner, but at least you don't have to read between the lines ( which is what happens all the time with Maeder's books - which is why they are great for experienced users). Wagner's book is still my favorite book on M programming.

Comment: @Leonid: Amazon lists 4 RM books. Do you have a recommendation for order to read them in?

Comment: @term-rewritica Yes, [I do](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/mathematica-for-computer-scientists/7596#7596)

Comment: @Leonid, I actually read your original post. Unfortunately, the sheer brilliance of the first two paragraphs blinded me from the wisdom of the rest of the post. :-) Learning mathematica has been quite an experience in hunting down out of print books. :-)

Comment: @term-rewritica Yes, best books for it you have to hunt for. Part of the fun :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To programmatically find the internal representation of the shortforms, you can use `MakeExpression`, which gives the result wrapped in `HoldComplete`. Here's an example:

```
MakeExpression@"?name"
(* HoldComplete[Information["name", LongForm -> False]] *)

MakeExpression@"??name"
(* HoldComplete[Information["name", LongForm -> True]] *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple of alternatives to R.M's method for seeing what *Mathematica* makes of input.

The input forms of every line entered are stored in the `DownValues` of `In`.
Starting with a new session or after using `Quit[]`, evaluating each in a separate Cell:

```
?Mod

??Plus

DownValues[In]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[In[1]] :> Information["Mod", LongForm -> False], 
>  HoldPattern[In[2]] :> Information["Plus", LongForm -> True], 
>  HoldPattern[In[3]] :> DownValues[In]}
> ```

Alternatively you could set a `$Pre` function to echo input:

```
$Pre = Function[, Print@Unevaluated@#; #, HoldAll];

?Plus
```

> ```
> Information["Plus", LongForm -> False]
> ```
>
> x+y+z represents a sum of terms.  >>