# Error when using FullForm with ?symbol

Tags: warning-messages

`Information[symbol]` shows information about a symbol and is equivalent to `?symbol`.

```
Information[symbol]
?symbol
```

> Global`symbol

```
Information[symbol, LongForm -> True]
??symbol
```

> Global`symbol

Using `FullForm` with `?symbol` returns the following error:

```
FullForm[Unevaluated[?symbol]]
```

> Syntax::bktmcp: Expression "Unevaluated[?symbol]]" has no closing "]".
>
> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .

But using `FullForm` with `Information[Unevaluated[symbol]]` returns the following expression without any error:

```
FullForm[Unevaluated[Information[symbol]]]
```

> Unevaluated[Information[symbol,Rule[LongForm,False]]]

Why does this happen?

Comment: my guess: Because you can't simply pass `? x` as argument to a function, since `?x` is not a symbol. i.e one can't make a symbol called "?" But The front end FE on the other hand simply parses this for you (it is being nice) and then converts internally to `Information[x]` and that is why it works now as argument to `FullForm` but you can't pass "? x" yourself as argument. It is meant to be used just for asking help on the FE only. I mean, only FE can parse this as first token read. Again, only a guess.

Comment: Very similar question but asked from a different angle: [(8126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8126/121) (I am not marking as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to special parsing just as I described in:
[Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/infix-form-of-putappend-does-not-work-with-variable/30490#30490).

- You cannot assume that all input forms are valid syntax at an arbitrary place in an expression.

It was my interest in seeing how *Mathematica* was interpreting certain input (that is, what Box expression were being sent to the Kernel) that lead me to ask [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121)

---

Incidentally I just discovered that if I copy the expression out of a String rather than typing it directly it is accepted as valid input:

[image]

I can't explain why the copy makes a difference (I don't think it *should*) but we can see that it does by looked at the Cell Expressions (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>):

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"FullForm", "[", 
  RowBox[{"Unevaluated", "[", 
   RowBox[{"?", "symbol"}], "]"}], "]"}]], "Input"]

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"FullForm", "[", 
  RowBox[{"Unevaluated", "[", 
   RowBox[{"?", "symbol]]"}]}]}]], "Input"]
```

Notice the unmatched brackets in the second expression, causing the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can this question be categorized as a "bug"?

Comment: @M6299 You're welcome.  I don't think it's a bug.  I think rather, as stated, it is a nonstandard parsing designed for convenience, and it only works properly at the beginning of a line.