# How to get short definition of all built in Mathematica Functions?

Tags: functions, programming, built-in-symbols

The first post in "Mathematica Weekly Newsletter - Tuesday, December 30, 2014" really attracted my attention as I was always looking for a complete list of built in Mathematica functions with short definition.  This post provided me a starting point. As we all know 
Link [1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AlphabeticalListing.html) and Link [2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NewIn100AlphabeticalListing.html) provide us Alphabetical Listing of all built in Mathematica functions.

With the help of the post Link [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69627/how-would-i-return-a-random-mathematica-command?newsletter=1&nlcode=335157%7C8e59), I can write the following codes:

```
    firstletters = {"A*", "$A*", "B*", "$B*", "C*", "$C*", "D*", "$D*", 
   "E*", "$E*", "F*", "$F*", "G*", "$G*", "H*", "$H*", "I*", "$I*", 
   "J*", "$J*", "K*", "$K*", "L*", "$L*", "M*", "$M*", "N*", "$N*", 
   "O*", "$O*", "P*", "$P*", "Q*", "$Q*", "R*", "$R*", "S*", "$S*", 
   "T*", "$T*", "U*", "$U*", "V*", "$V*", "W*", "$W*", "X*", "$X*", 
   "Y*", "$Y*", "Z*", "$Z*"};
functionslist = Flatten[Names[#] & /@ firstletters];
```

Now I hope that I have a complete list of mathematica functions in my functionslist (if it does not have a complete list of functions, please help me how to get it). Length[functionslist] gives me 5267 number.

Now I want each function with short definition. For example `functionslist[[1]]` gives me "AASTriangle". If I type

```
?AASTriangle
```

I get the following:

```
(*AASTriangle[\[Alpha],\[Beta],a] returns a filled triangle with angles \[Alpha] and \[Beta] and side length a, where a is adjacent to one angle only. >>*)
```

I wonder why

```
?(functionslist[[1]])
```

does not give me the same result as above?

I am trying to create a notebook with all functions and their short definitions. If I could make this, it would make my life easy. Please help.

Sorry, for this lengthy question.

Comment: I'd use what Bill showed, but another option is `Information[Evaluate[ToExpression[functionslist[[1]]]]]`

Comment: Column[Information /@ functionslist]

Comment: Closely related: [(8126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8126/121)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use the built in function `Information`, which is the programmatic form of `??`

```
Information[#, LongForm -> False] & /@ functionslist
```

gives a long list of (short) function definitions. By the way... it's easy to figure this kind of thing out -- in this case, I highlighted the symbol ?? (double question mark) and pressed the F1 key to bring up the help. That brought me to the function `Information`. I had first tried help on the single question mark (which brought me to the function `Definition`) which didn't seem quite right.

Here is the very start of the output...

[image]

Comment: @ bill s, you are genius. Thank you. I would like to leave this question if I could get some formatted results. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Any Idea why we get "Attributes[ExternalFunctionName]={Protected,ReadProtected}" or "Attributes[OverwriteTarget]={Protected}" 
in some cases?

Comment: It looks like most of these have some form of Protected attributes, so probably is related to that. I imagine you could set up some sort of filter (`Select`, `DeleteCases` or some such) to remove them if necessary. But it's hard for me to imagine what this is going to be used for... it's long and quite unwieldy. Why not just use the help?

Comment: @ bill s, thanks for update. I am trying to make a small book with all these functions so that I can review in my leisure time.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the usage messages:

```
usageInfo = With[{func = Symbol[#]}, func::usage] &;

cF = Column[Style[#, 16, "Usage", Background -> None] & /@ #,
            Dividers -> All, Background -> {{LightBlue, LightOrange}}] &;

usageInfo /@ functionslist[[;;8]] // cF
```

[image]

Alternatively, make the usage message content a `Hyperlink` to the docs page:

```
usageInfo2 = With[{func = Symbol[#]}, 
    Hyperlink[Style[func::usage, 14, "Panel", Background -> None], 
     "paclet:ref/" <> ToString[func], ActiveStyle -> None]] &;

usageInfo2 /@ functionslist[[;; 8]] // 
       Column[#, Dividers -> All, Background -> {{LightBlue, LightOrange}}] &
```

[image]

Comment: @ kguler, thank you for taking your time to answer this question. Your answers are always very detail and informative. As always, a big thank you.

Comment: @ramesh, my pleasure..