# Is ? and Information equivalent? Are they the same in Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

Both in V10.2:

**Windows**
[image]

**Linux**
[image]

So is `?` not the same as `Information`? But in the help files, it looks like `?` is a short form for `Information` ??

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(8126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8126/121)

Answer (score 5):

This looks very weird indeed.  Here's my theory on what happens.

---

First, what is `?something` equivalent to exactly?  It's the same as

```
Information["something", LongForm -> False]
```

Note that I wrote `"something"` in quotes.  This is not exactly the same as `Information[something]` (without quotes).  `?` is one of those operators that, when appearing at the beginning of the line, will cause the following characters to be interpreted as a string.  `<<` is another example of such an operator.

Keeping this subtlety in mind, `?` and `Information` behave in exactly the same way.

---

Now what about the second weirdness, i.e. that if using a symbol name (not a string), then `Information` does return the usage message even though the VariationalMethods package was not loaded?

My best guess is that it's because the usage messages for the standard add-ons are replaced by Mathematica with messages stored in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/TextResources/Language/Usage.m` (replace `Language` by your version's language, typically English).  I think this is both to allow translations and to have nicely formatted messages with 2D math inside.

It seems that symbols from builtin packages seem to be in this strange state of semi-existence that `Names` will claim that they don't exist but creating them will immediately load their usage message.  This is very similar to the `Stub` attribute, but `` Attributes["VariationalMethods`VariationalD"] `` doesn't find the symbol either.

Comment: I think your first observation is correct; consider `MakeExpression[RowBox[{"?", "foo"}], StandardForm]`

Comment: I gave this same explaination, perhaps in a bit more detail, in answer to [(91216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91216/121), only to follow the **Linked** question and see this existing answer of yours.  I think these two questions are effectively the same, and I would like to merge them.  Do you consider that appropriate?  And if I do merge them do you feel that my answer will infringe upon yours?

Comment: Actually, after a bit of consideration I am closing this question as a duplicate of [(8126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8126/121) as it does not introduce new material.  However [(91216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91216/121) *does* raise a new question, though as it happens you already answered it here.  How should we handle this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree that it is a duplicate.  I'm not particularly worried about this kind of "infringement" :-)  Go ahead and merge if you like.

Answer (score 2):

`Information` has an option `LongForm`.

`?...` is equivalent to

Information[..., LongForm -> False]

`??...` is equivalent to

Information[..., LongForm -> True]

Comment: So either way, `Information[]` is equivalent to one of the `?` or `??`. But neither `[1]` nor `[2]` is working, while `[3]` is working.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is, (from the linux screenshot), if there is equivalence, I would expect Input[1] or Input[2] to have the same Output as [3].

Comment: I think the reason for `[3]` working is explained in [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91218/3066) to your other question.

Comment: Yes, in this case, that makes sense. I will play around more with these in different order, with fresh kernels.

Comment: Perhaps "equivalent" is too strong a term. The front-end processing for `?` and `??`, done to translate them into their `FullForm`, is different from what the more formal `Information[...]` receives, and that may account for the difference you see. "translates to" might be a better term than "equivalent"