# Search the neighborhood area along a line in an image

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to search for the black areas along a line (the horizontal line shown below). Though it is straight in this picture, it could be of irregular shape in other cases. It seems that the ImageTake function can only take rectangle areas. Can anyone tell me how to limit the processing within the line neighborhood area, and mark the black area in the left part?

[image]

Update: Several raw images without red marks:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Update2: Other cases with bigger black area somewhere else
[image]

Comment: Please post one (or a few if you can) images without the red label for us to be able to test some approaches

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
i = {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjTp9.png", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuHP7.png", 
     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFkNM.png"};
i1 = Import /@ i;

i2 = ColorNegate /@ Binarize /@ i1;

m = Dilation[#, 10]&/@ (Binarize[#, .8]&/@ ImageAdjust/@ DistanceTransform /@ i2);

Grid@{i1, ColorCombine[ {#1, #1, #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{i1, m}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh fantastic! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanna achieve

Comment: I seriously need to learn functional programming.

Comment: @jmlopez Well, that make us two

Comment: I've been trying to get a book on this (Power Programming With Mathematica) but I just can't find it. I guess I'll just learn by reading all the clever answers in here.

Comment: Actually after some test I found a problem. When there is a big black area somewhere else, the small ones would be eliminated.

Comment: @Tinza123 post some examples, please

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to resize the image the first time. Now its up.

Comment: @Tinza123 Except for the size, that black hole is indistinguishable from your targets. If filtering by size is enough for you, 'ComponentMeasurements[..."Area"]' will do. If not, please tell what characteristic do you think could be used to tell the 2 cases apart

Comment: Really appreciate for your time. I want to use the absolute width property as a criteria, and thanks for the hint, I found ComponentMeasurements[..."Width"] seems to do the job. And as to this specific picture, I want to keep both of them (the small one as well as the big one).

Comment: @Tinza123 Ok. Let us know if you need further help

Comment: Actually I do have one further question. I used ImageLines to generate the line: lines = ImageLines[GradientFilter[#, 1]] & /@ i2; Is there any convenient way that I can select all components which have intersections with the line?

Comment: @Tinza123 yes, but it is too much code to post in a comment. Do you want to post a question?

Comment: Yeah sure. I'll do it in a minute.

Comment: @Tinza123 Oh well, I arrived late there

Comment: @jmlopez Get the book for free here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/193 ... courtesy of a fellow user :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link green/belisarius!!! I hope now I have a better chance at understanding more of *Mathematica*.