# Confused about Unevaluated

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation

Why does

```
Map[Unevaluated, Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

give

> {Unevaluated[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], Unevaluated[{{0, -I}, {I, 0}}], Unevaluated[{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]}

while

```
Table[Unevaluated[PauliMatrix[i]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

gives

> {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}

I think they should give the same result! Why not?

Comment: It's just that `Table` evaluates it's arguments in a non-standard way.  In particular, it Holds it's arguments, explicitly evaluates the second argument (the iterator), substitutes values obtained from the iterator into the first argument and then (importantly!) explicitly evaluates the first argument at those values.

Comment: @MarkMcClure But according to the docs of `Map`. Map always effectively constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it. And use `Trace`, I found in the last three steps, _mathematica_ actually remove the `Unevaluated`, and finally bring back the `Unevaluated` head, why?

Comment: I'm just saying that `Table` evaluates it's arguments in a non-standard way and (by implication) that `Map` does not. Thus, when the documentation says that `Map` "constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it", it does so in the standard way. Thus, `Map[Unevaluated,{1,2}]` produces the same output as `{Unevaluated[1],Unevaluated[2]}`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure You're telling me that the step "then evaluate it" in `Map` and the step 'substitutes values ....explicitly evaluates the first argument at those values' in `Table` is two kind of evaluate?!! I still don't understand, Now that `Table` has the attributes `HoldAll`, it should hold the `Unevaluated`. It seems that "expr, shift+Enter" and "Evaluate[expr]" is different ? And Map use the first one `Table` use the second?

Comment: Yes. Try your "two kinds of evaluate" with `Unevaluated[1+1]` as input vs `Evaluate[Unevaluated[1+1]]` as the input.

Comment: Now, I'm not claiming to fully understand the whole deal here (which is why I wrote a comment, rather than an answer). I'm simply stating that `Table` and `Map` have different evaluation procedures and that's what leads to this behavior. Also, functions like `Unevaluated` and attributes like `HoldAll` are intimately connected with these issues.

Comment: If you interesting in how evaluation is done to extent of using `Trace`, you are ready for [David Wagner's book](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21451/3066). It will answer your question and many, many more. In particular, see Chapter 7.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thank you very much

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for recommending the very good book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer isn't so much related to `Map` or  `Table`, but to `Unevalauted` and the evaluation sequence.

The first one

```
Map[Unevaluated, {1, 2}]

(* {Unevaluated[1], Unevaluated[2]} *)
```

All the heads and arguments are inert, and none has heads `Evaluate` or `Unevaluated` to worry about. Note that the symbol `Unevaluated` doesn't have head `Unevaluated`.
Just apply the mapping downvalue to get `{Unevalauted[1], Unevaluated[2]}`

Now,

```
Table[Unevaluated@i, {i, 2}]

(* {1, 2} *)
```

Strip `Unevaluated` from the head of the argument `Unevaluated@i`. Now it's just like `Table[i, {i,2}]` giving `{1, 2}`.

Comment: yeah! I notice it from `Trace`. _Mathematica_ just simply strip `Unevaluated` away in the `Table` in the first step. But why?

Comment: @matheorem that's equivalent to asking why MMA evaluates first the head. It's part of the evaluation sequence to strip the `Unevaluated`s. It's useful when you want to pass arguments to functions before they are evaluated. For example, `Map[Hold, Unevaluated@{2+2, 3+7}]`

Comment: Well, you mean the result of evaluating the head `Unevaluated` is just strip it, right?

Comment: @matheorem. No. `Unevaluated[something]` is inert. I'm mean it gets stripped. `Unevaluated` is very special, you couldn't replace it with, for example, `Identity`.

Comment: What does inert mean? Are there any other head that are inert too?

Comment: @matheorem with inert I just meant that it evaluates to itself, it doesn't change when evaluated. Just like `{2, 3}`, or `Hold[5]`, `Unevaluated[whatever]` evaluates to itself. `Identity`, on the other hand, evaluates to its contents, or "strips `Identity` upon evaluation". `Unevaluated` isn't stripped when the `Unevaluated[something]` is evaluated. It is stripped when something that has it as argument is evaluated. That is very special behaviour, unique to `Unevaluated`

Comment: I think I understand. Clear explanation, Thank you very much!

Comment: I agree with this analysis. I guess this behavior of `Unevaluated` is exactly why we use it in a case like `Length[Unevaluated[1+2+3]]`. An even simpler example would be `f[x_]=x^2; f[Unevaluated[2]]`.