# Where to begin?

Tags: reference-request

I was looking at the Mathematica website today and just decided to buy the software. I've spent too much time juggling annoying symbolic expressions by hand that actually learning to do things with a computer should be a worthwhile investment. Similarly for making conjectures about formulas etc. a computer would seem like a useful tool.

My question: Where should I begin? I have a Ph.D. in math and would consider myself an expert level programmer in C, C++, x86 assembler, OCaml and Perl. I understand the functional programming paradigm well, so I don't need any introductions. To begin with, I would like to be able to work efficiently with linear algebra, number theory and random sampling. Oh, and plotting would be nice too and how to embed formulas written in LaTeX into those plots.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you already seen the series of books by Trott? They're somewhat bulky and a bit expensive, but if your nearby library has them, you could take a look and see if it suits you. Otherwise, I would suggest also taking a look at Wagon's *Mathematica in Action*; I personally found the examples there very instructive, and the skills used to be quite generalizable.

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/mathematica/

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: Thanks guys. That discussion about programming references seems like a great place to start after having watched the few intro videos.

Comment: Regarding plotting, [see here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html).  The documentation is pretty good and has plenty of examples. You don't write LaTeX in Mathematica. Instead write your equations directly using Mma's front end.

Comment: ...but if need be, you can use *Mathematica* to produce $\LaTeX$ (though, not always optimal $\LaTeX$).

Comment: My comment with LaTeX is mostly that if I use it to generate graphs for publications, I would like my labels to look the same as the formulas in the text.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get used to it quickly, but to start with I would advocate a little hesitation before extrapolating your experience with other languages to *Mathematica*, because despite many superficial similarities, it really is quite different to almost anything else. A particularly good and reasonably paced reference for the *programming* side of *Mathematica* (rather than the mathematical or presentation aspects) is [David Wagner's book](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724), now freely available thanks to the hard work and persistence of several of our own community members.

Comment: Well, I only expect to understand syntax easily, but not too much else. I know languages have their caveats. A line by line transformation of an OCaml function is often very slow in Haskell due to thunking etc. so I definitely do not expect to pick it up quickly.

Comment: Browse mathematica stack exchange -- once you get to the point where you are answering questions, you'll find it's a great way to learn.

Comment: You probably have found the following pages in the built in documentation center, but to be sure: [random sampling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html), [number theory](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NumberTheory.html), [linear algebra overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraOverview.html) [linear algebra guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html).

Comment: Btw there is a [30 day trial](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/), so you could try that first before buying.

Comment: Some Mathematica-specific caveats: since you know other functional languages, keep in mind that the basic data structure in Mathematica in an array (of expressions), not a linked list. Ways to make things fast are: avoid mutable state, vectorize (as in MATLAB, if you're familiar with it: if `a`, `b` are vectors, `a*b` is much faster than `MapThread[Times, {a,b}]`), and use [built-in functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html) as much as possible. Learn how to juggle and transform Mathematica expressions (this is done *a lot*, in complex ways).

Comment: Make sure you understand that *everything is an expression* (including code), understand pattern matching and that "function definitions" such as `f[x_]:=x^2` are just transformation rules in reality, read a bit about the evaluation sequence. Understand and learn about `FullForm`, `Head`, `ReplaceAll`, `Map`, `Apply`, `Table` (and `Do`), `Select`, `Cases`, `Function`. Avoid `For` as much as you can while you're a beginner (there's `Do` instead). This is pretty dense, but hopefully it'll give you a very quick start (given your past experience with programming languages). Ask when you get stuck.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you register on this site! (I noticed you didn't, which means you might even lose commenting rights on this question if you clear your cookies.)

Answer (score 1):

I found this book to be extremely useful in learning advanced functionalities in Mathematica: 
"Mathematica Cookbook" of Sal Mangano
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521004.do

It has many examples of matrices and plots uses and several tips from other topics and uses that go beyond the documentation's.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin? I'd pick a problem that is easy, but not trivial, and work it out in Mathematica. After a couple of such exercises, you'll be ready to use it in your real work. Since you mention linear algebra, how about something that gets you using `EigenSystem` or `SingularValueDecomposition`? Or maybe you have something you'd like to plot? There are great commands like `Plot` and `Plot3D`, but for data you would use `ListPlot` or `ListPlot3D`. Or stretch out and try `GraphPlot` or `GraphPlot3D`, you can visualize most anything. And then there's `Manipulate` that let's you animate your plot to see how things change with particular parameter values. Surely you have some data somewhere you've always meant to visualize? And there are a zillion functions involving randomness, like `RandomVariate` for generating random points/vectors/matrices but also symbolic commands that know a surprising amount about different distributions. Hang out here for a while wrestle with some questions... in no time you'll be answering them, and that's the best way to learn. And don't worry, we won't hold that Ph.D. against you.