# The Flat Attribute, Unevaluated and the Evaluation Process

Tags: programming, evaluation, attributes

To make this question easy to follow let's give some symbols a couple attributes.

```
Attributes[f] = {Flat};
Attributes[s] = {Orderless};
```

Now consider the following:

`f[a, b, g[c, d], f[e, h], j, k]` gives

> `f[a, b, g[c, d], e, h, j, k]`

as expected since f is `Flat`

Now, we wrap `Unevaluated` around `f`

```
f[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[f[e, h]], j, k]
```

This gives

> `f[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[e], Unevaluated[h], j, k]`

To understand what happened here, we use `Trace`

```
f[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[f[e, h]], j, k] // Trace
```

> ```
>  {f[a, b, g[c, d], f[e, h], j, k], f[a, b, g[c, d], e, h, j, k], f[a,
>  b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[e], Unevaluated[h], j, k]}
> ```

Finally, let's also wrap `Unevaluated` around `s`.

```
f[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[f[e, h]], Unevaluated[s[n, m]], j, k]
```

> ```
> f[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[e], Unevaluated[h], 
>  Unevaluated[s[n, m]], j, k]
> ```

Now, here comes my question/confusion. In the case of `f`, the `Unevaluated` head was removed, so the elements of `f`( that has a `Flat` attribute ) was now spliced in and the `Unevaluated` head replaced on the elements of `f`. According to the standard evaluation process, if any part of an expression has the form `Unevaluated[expr]`, we replace that part with `expr` and keep a record of the original expression (So we can later replace the `Unevaluated` head). Now as I've shown, if the expression `expr` has a head with `Flat` `Attribute`, then the expression gets spliced in (i.e. it actually gets evaluated) but as we saw with `s` that has the `Orderless` `Attribute`, the expression remains unevaluated as described by the Evaluation process. So why does the `Flat` attribute supersede `Unevaluated`? This shouldn't be the case according to the standard evaluation process. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of `Unevaluated`, but is not fully covered in the documentation. `Unevaluated` is a special head that *changes the attributes temporarily* so that the function `f` holds its argument. It is supposed to work as if you had given it one of the `HoldFirst/HoldAll`, etc. attribute, but only for that evaluation. The key point though, is that the function `f` **does not know** about `Unevaluated`. This is covered in David Wagner's book, ["Power programming with Mathematica: The Kernel"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/5):

> The beauty of `Unevaluated` is that it is invisible to the function being called — it makes the function temporarily behave as though it had one of the `Hold-` attributes. [...] `Unevaluated` may seem similar to `Hold`, but there is an important difference: `Hold` (or `HoldForm`) is visible to the function being called. [...]
>
> [...] the special behavior of `Unevaluated` is accomplished by **removing the head `Unevaluated` from an expression before rules for the surrounding expression are applied and restoring the head to the expression afterward if no applicable rules were found.**

So what happens is:

- The head `Unevaluated` is removed and `f` given a temporary `Hold` like attribute
- The existing rules for `f` are applied. This causes the expression to be flattened out, because of its `Flat` attribute.
- `Unevaluated` is restored to the expression, or whatever remains of it now.

This is exactly what you also see in the `Trace` output.

You can simply change the outermost head to verify that this behaviour is due to `Unevaluated` being invisible to the outer function `f`:

```
g[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated@f[e, h], s[n, m], j, k]
(* g[a, b, g[c, d], Unevaluated[f[e, h]], s[m, n], j, k] *)
```

Comment: So why doesn't the same thing happen to the `s` (with `Orderless` attribute) function? How come that expression remains the same?

Comment: @RunnyKine There are no rules in the surroundings that affects `s`, so it remains the same.