# Defining functions that reference other values

Tags: functions

How could I define a function that references other values?

eg

```
a = 2 x; b = 4 k;
f[k_, x_] := a^b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808), I would strongly advise against using this kind of constructs, which in essence use global variables. However, if you must do this, here is one easy way:

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, k, f];
a = 2 x; b = 4 k;
f[k_, x_] =  a^b
```

that is, use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` - in which case your r.h.s. will be computed at the time of the assignment.

Here is another method, which might be somewhat safer:

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, k, f];
a = 2 x; b = 4 k;
f[kk_, xx_] := Block[{x = xx, k = kk}, a^b]
```

that is, use `Block` to dynamically localize `x` and `k`, then call your code (`a^b` here).

But again, the best (safest) way is to make all functions (`a` and `b` here) explicitly take the parameters, and pass the parameters explicitly (as explained in the link I gave).

Comment: @ Leonid Shifrin, thank you for your answer - it is not absolutely necessary for me, so I think I will take your advice & keep it all within the function definition itself (though it is rather long!) - but it is good to know that there is a way - again, many thanks for your help on this - I will have a look at the link you provided to understand better the technical aspects.

Comment: @martin - section 4.5 [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/363) has a nice explanation of `Block`.