# Want explanation of when different looping constructs are appropriate

Tags: list-manipulation, map

For example when would you use a `Do` loop over a `For` loop? For which tasks would you use `Map`, `Table`, `Scan`, et cetera? I'm quite new to *Mathematica* and I don't really get what the advantages of any of these loops are over the standard `For` loop whose use seems to be so harshly discouraged here on StackExchange.

Comment: Regarding `Do` vs `For`: if you can use `Do`, do not use `For`.  `For` is less readable and introduces global variables which you'd have to localize manually.  `For` is not generally *standard*, it is just a convenient construct in some procedural languages.  If you compare code using For with code equivalent using Do, it should be clear why Do is usually much more convenient in Mathematica.

Comment: Regarding functional vs procedural (Table/Map vs Do), the functional approach typically gives better performance and more concise and readable code in Mathematica.  You'll of course need to get used to thinking in terms of these constructs first, and if you're used to writing C code, using these will not come naturally right away.

Comment: But in any case - use whatever makes you happy. Once performance becomes important, you´ll notice the differences. Otherwise your question is rather broad...

Comment: `Do` can directly loop over the elements of a list, `For` can't. Compare `Do[Print[i],{i,myList}]` vs `For[i=1,i<Length[myList],i++,Print[myList[[i]]]]`. Of course, `Map (/@)` is shorter: `Print/@myList`.

Comment: You are new, so you will be tempted to use the most general and powerful functions, and the ones you are most used to from other languages. `For`, `Part`, etc. That's great, you can

Comment: However, as time goes by, you'll learn more specific functions that will have, when they are applicable, advantages, either in computational efficiency, readability, debugability, etc.

Comment: In the particular case of `For`, I think it's our collective experience that you very very rarely need to go "so general"; almost always there's a better alternative.

Comment: I recommend you download and read Wagner's book, in particular, chapter 4. You can download the book for free [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/3066).

Comment: Check out this question, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica Should cover most of the cases.