# How symbol lookup actually works

Tags: bugs, packages, documentation, contexts, compatibility

**Bug introduced in V6 and fixed in V11.3**

> The behavior indeed changed but now the documentation is clear about it.

---

This code is inconsistent with the description from [*Power Programming with Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724):

```
x = 5;
temp`x = 6;
Begin["temp`"]
{x, Global`x, temp`x}
```

The result in my Mathematica session is `{5, 5, 6}`, but it's `{6, 5, 6}` in Section 8.1.1 of [*Power Programming with Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724) (page 231 of the hardcopy or page 249 of the PDF).

Comment: may be you found a bug in the book or a bug in Mathematica :)

Comment: Try this for more strange result: x = 5; Begin["temp`"]; x = 6; {x, Global`x} which gives {6,6} ?

Comment: @Nasser - If you use `BeginPackage` to put ``temp` `` on the context path it works, but this demo also needs a line break: ``x = 5; BeginPackage["temp`"]; (*line break*)
x = 6; {x, Global`x}``

Comment: The very same question was asked a couple of days ago.  At that time I noted that even the current v9 documentation is incorrect because it states that when looking for a symbol that was entered, Mathematica searches `$ContextPath` *after* searching `$Context`, even though in reality it searches `$ContextPath` *before* `$Context`

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting thing is that the Q and each A here got so many upvotes in such a short time. My answer isn't even a full answer. Very suspicious.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Another interesting thing is that I didn't notice this question has already been asked……I usually have a quick scan at our homepage every day and in fact I knew this question might be asked around Mar 4, but I still overlooked it. Very suspicious :D

Comment: @Kuba Please re-read the [documentation for `$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html?q=%24ContextPath), because this list of contexts should be searched *after* the symbol cannot be found in `$Context`. Since `Begin` resets the current context, the behaviour is surprising and in the book, the results are different.

Comment: @halirutan will do, thanks. Haven't thought that through.

Comment: I think it would be useful to move the answers below to the original question.  This can be done with a Merge.  If anyone disagrees please let me know soon.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This behaviour has changed since that book was published.  I am writing this additional answer to make it clear how Mathematica 9 searches contexts for symbols and that even the current version 9 documentation is incorrect in describing this.

#### How symbol lookup actually works

When you enter a symbol name such as `x`, Mathematica will check if a symbol with this name already exists.  It will first search the contexts from `$ContextPath` for `x`, one by one.  If it doesn't find it there, it'll search the context from `$Context` for it.  If it still doesn't find it, then it will *create* a new symbol named `x` in `$Context`.

Thus `$ContextPath` controls where to *look for* symbols, while `$Context` controls where to *create* new symbols.

Your observations are explained by these rules, noting that `Begin` will change `$Context` only but not `$ContextPath`.  Note that [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BeginPackage.html) will change both `$Context` and `$ContextPath`.

#### Warning: the documentation contains an error in Mathematica versions older than 11.3.

The [`$ContextPath` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html) states that

> `$ContextPath` is a global variable that gives a list of contexts, *after* `$Context`, to search in trying to find a symbol that has been entered.

In fact `$ContextPath` is searched *before* `$Context` in the current version.

[In old versions this was not the case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43624/12), as the Wagner book describes.  I don't know when the change happened.

The [Contexts tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) does correctly state the order of search in the current version:

> Since `$Context` is searched after `$ContextPath`, you can think of it as having "." appended to the file search path.

Comment: Was this reported?

Comment: @Kuba Is everybody sure that this is really just one more documentation bug? Maybe it is not. I at least find the documented behaviour and Wagner's description more intuitive. Someone (@Daniel Lichtblau ?) from WRI should react.

Comment: @RolfMertig : Danny Lichtblau and I are looking into this.

Comment: @Stefan Anything to report at this time?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It looks like the behavior was intentionally changed in V6, but the documentation was not properly updated. It has been reported internally but not fixed so far.

Comment: @StefanR Is there a particular reason why this is not yet fixed in the documentation?  I am asking because if my understanding of how name lookup works is not accurate, I would like to know about it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Looks like we just haven't gotten around to it yet (it's in our bugs database).

Comment: @StefanR Still present in v.11.  Can you prioritize fixing this documentation?  It is extremely confusing, and the same bug exists in the Contexts tutorial
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html 
(In the first table.)  
It also deserves a place of prominence is "what's new in Mma 6", but I could not find it there at all.  Thanks.

Comment: This bug was just brought to my attention today--it is unfortunate that the original developer ignored the report.  I have done the minimal fix of getting the main usage right.  It looks to me like this page needs some love, so I'll add it to my queue of reference pages in need of review.  And just to confirm: this was intentionally changed in V6.  The wording was updated in several other places but missed here.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev looks fine in 11.3, thanks! Szabolcs, maybe the answer needs an update then.

Answer (score 19):

Not an answer. Just screen shot. I booted up version 2.2 to verify the book result. And it does verify:

[image: screenshot]

The same result we get with version 5.2:

[image: screenshot]

---

Something changed since the book was written (screenshot from version 9 follows):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

It appears since version 3 shadowed variables are given priority, as demonstrated below.  In the `` temp` `` context `x` is taken as `` temp`x `` unless `` Global`x `` exists.

```
Remove[temp`x, Global`x]
temp`x = 6;
Begin["temp`"];
{x, Global`x}
End[];
```

> {6, x}

```
Remove[temp`x, Global`x]
temp`x = 6;
x = 5;
Begin["temp`"];
{x, Global`x}
End[];
```

> {5, 5}

Comment: Isn't what happens that contexts from `$ContextPath` are searched for names *before* `$Context`?  (While it is still true that *new* symbols are created in `$Context`.)  Then the documentation of `$ContextPath` is simply incorrect because it says: "`$ContextPath` is a global variable that gives a list of contexts, *after* `$Context`, to search in trying to find a symbol that has been entered."

Comment: (This is the same thing that you are saying, put in a different way.)

Comment: `BeginPackage` ... `EndPackage` puts ``temp` `` at the beginning of the `$ContextPath` but `Begin` ... `End` does not change the `$ContextPath`.

Answer (score 12):

This is because of `$ContextPath`. If the symbol outside the `Begin`/`End` is created in a context that is listed in `$ContextPath`, *Mathematica* will recognize it as belonging to that context even when called from a different context (even if `Begin`/`End` is put in a package file and called via `Get`):

```
$ContextPath
```

> ```
> {"DocumentationSearch`", "ResourceLocator`", "PacletManager`",
>  "QuantityUnits`", "WebServices`", "System`", "Global`"}
> ```

```
WebServices`x;
Begin["temp`"];
Print@Context@x;
End[];
```

> ```
>  WebServices`
> ```

Now if I remove `` "WebServices`" `` from `$ContextPath`:

```
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "WebServices`"];
WebServices`x;
Begin["temp`"];
Print@Context@x;
End[];
```

> ```
> temp`
> ```

Now what has changed in related code in successive versions, I have no idea.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that when the book appeared, the behaviour of how a symbol is resolved was different. We have two important things:

- the current `$Context` which is usually `` Global` ``  unless you change it with e.g. `Begin` as you did
- the `$ContextPath` which is a list of contexts that are searched when you type in a symbol like `x` without explicit context

Now there seems to be confusion how a symbol is found. The documentation to [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html) reads

> `$ContextPath` is a global variable that gives a list of contexts, after `$Context`, to search in trying to find a symbol that has been entered.

This suggests that it is *first* checked whether a symbol is in the current `$Context` and *after* that all entries in `$ContextPath` are checked.

This is how it seemed to work when the book was written and it is completely understandable that you are confused why it behaves differently. In [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) it is written the other way around

> Since `$Context` is searched after `$ContextPath`, you can think of it as having "." appended to the file search path.

Therefore, let me explain your code as I understand what happens.

```
x=5  
temp`x=6;
{x,temp`x}
```

You create two symbols in different contexts, the first one in `` Global` ``  and the last one in `` temp` `` . As I understand it, the `x` in the last line is the global `x` because the context `` Global` ``  is in `$ContextPath` rather than because your current `$Context` is `` Global` ``

```
Begin["temp`"]
{x,Global`x}
{temp`x,Global`x}
End[]
```

With the `Begin` you set `$Context` to `` temp` `` , but that doesn't matter, because when you refer to `x`, it is found first in the `` Global` ``  context which is an element of your `$ContextPath`. The rest should be clear, because when you specify the context of a symbol explicitly, there is no room for guessing.

Finally, please note that you can refer to the symbol `x` in the current context (meaning in `$Context`) by using  `` `x `` and therefore

```
Begin["temp`"]
`x
End[]
```

will give 6.

### Appendix

I haven't seen that almost the same question was already asked and has an answer which goes along what I wrote. Another important aspect was mentioned there that I haven't said: `$Context` controls where a new symbol is created (if there couldn't be found an existing one). Please read the following:

[Result about Context is inconsistent with the description of “Power Programming with Mathematica”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/187)

Comment: [The documentation is not accurate about how symbol lookup works](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12)

Comment: I believe `$Context` controls where symbols are *created*, but it doesn't control where existing symbols are searched for.  That's controlled by `$ContextPath`.

Comment: @Szabolcs If this were true, how is ``temp`x=1`` found when I call `x` inside ``Begin["temp`"]``? `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/97JkJ.png"]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Nevertheless, really embarrassing that I typed the whole answer without searching whether it already existed..

Comment: I was sloppy in my comment, see my answer for the full story.  If you enter a symbol name without a context, Mma first looks for it in the contexts from `$ContextPath`.  If it's not there, then it also looks in `$Context`.  If it's not there, it creates it in `$Context`.  The documentation is incorrect in that it it claims that `$Context` is searched before `$ContextPath` while it's searched only afterwards.  In older versions it was the reverse (at least in v2.2 according to Nasser).

Comment: It's not embarrassing, don't we do it all the time? There are 23000 questions on the site, it's pretty hard for me to find duplicates .... unless I've already seen them and I remember.

Comment: I remembered now, this was asked before I posted an answer now, but deleted it. Will make community answer instead, just for documentation

Answer (score 6):

(this is wiki answer, as just noticed it is duplicate, but will keep it here for easy reference)

The result is different from Version 2.2 and version 10.1, this is just to show the difference. Something changed between 1993 and today:

[image]

Comment: Ahh I see the duplication, perhaps it's best to merge the answers? The complete descriptions given here are really insightful. Usually I can see a potential duplication when typing the question, but I just missed the referenced one?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following also fits the present discussion.

### Who shadows whom?

When you run

```
(*cleanup*)
$Context = "Global`";
Quiet@Remove["temp`*", "Global`*"];
(*--*)
Global`x = "global";
BeginPackage["temp`"];
temp`x = "temp";
```

The last line generates the message

`` ...::shdw: Symbol x appears in multiple contexts {temp`,Global`}; definitions in context temp` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >> ``

```
(*cleanup*)
$Context = "Global`";
Quiet@Remove["temp`*", "hemp`*", "Global`*"];
(*--*)
BeginPackage["temp`"];
temp`x = "temp";
Global`x = "global";
```

generates

`` ...::shdw: Symbol x appears in multiple contexts {Global`,temp`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >> ``

It looks like even the developer of this particular message was unsure about what exactly happens here ("*may* shadow *or be shadowed*").

The following would more correct in the first case:

`` ...::shdw: Symbol x appears in multiple contexts {temp`,Global`} on the context path. Definitions in the first context, temp`, will shadow any other definitions. >> ``

The message should be the same in the second case, the order of the contexts should be exactly as they are in `Append[$ContextPath, $Context]`.

#### Why is this message more correct?

A symbol `x` can be defined in multiple contexts *that are not on the context path* just fine, the following generates no error message:

```
Global`x = "global";
foo`x = "foo";
bar`x = "bar";
```

By the way: You get no error message if you later do `` AppendTo[$ContextPath, "foo`"] ``, even though the shadowing 'ambiguity' problem now exists.

The "::shdw" message should really be saying that within the set of contexts  `Append[$ContextPath, $Context]` ("the context path") there exist two or more symbols with `SymbolName` `x`.

The original message is not clear about which definition will be given precedence, although the system knows this unambiguously: When an unqualified symbol `x` appears, it will be searched in `Append[$ContextPath, $Context]` in-order (it will be created in `$Context` if it cannot be found).

`BeginPackage` *prepends* the mentioned context to the context path, such that its definitions will take precedence.

Comment: But no one asked about shadowing message, right?

Comment: Yes, but I think the message reflects the confusion about `$ContextPath` and `$Context` and which is given priority.

Comment: masterxilo, I see that this answer is going unappreciated, but I also see the effort you put into it.  In cases like this I think it is beneficial to post a new Question specifically tailored to this answer, then self-answer.  There is even a check-box in the interface **Answer your own question** because this kind of thing is anticipated.  (One could then delete this post.)