# Behavior of Remove inside a Package

Tags: packages, contexts

I have a notebook containing (in a Code cell, Initialization Group)

```
BeginPackage["aPackage`"];
aTestFunction::usage = "aTestFunction usage";
Begin["`Private`"];
(* Remove[aTestFunction]; *)
aTestFunction[arg_] := arg + 1;
Protect[aTestFunction];
End[];
EndPackage;
```

and further

```
Needs["aPackage`", NotebookFileName[]];
?aTestFunction
aTestFunction[1]
Quit[];
```

All that honestly earns its pay. But if I de - comment the `Remove` command, it produces.

> Information::notfound: "Symbol aTestFunction not found."

and I can' t  realize the reason. 
All things considered, `Remove` removes the `aTestFunction` symbol  (provided that it exists) from the `aPackage` context but should not prevent it from being defined at a later time. It sounds quite different from what one can observe in the `Global` context: this

```
Context[]
a = 1;
Remove[a];
a = 2;
a + 1
```

returns

```
Global
3
```

.

Comment: closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly:

Here what is going on, `aTestFunction` was created in `` aPackage` `` context, then you've removed it and since the current context is `` aPackage`Private` `` the definition of your function is created there.

More precisely:

New symbols are created in current `$Context` during read time, (*1*) the existance of `aTestFunction` between `BeginPackage` and `Begin` lines makes the `aTestFunction` an exported symbol (that means in `` aPackage` ``, because the symbol was not found and the current `$Context` is `` apackage` ``).

After (*2*) `Remove` it's no longer there and (*3*) your definition is read in `` aPackage`Private` `` context. But `` aPackage`Private` `` is not going to be on `$ContextPath` or `$Context` after `EndPackage[]` so it is not found by `?`.

I'm strongly encouraging to read a very nice answer of Szabolcs:

[**How symbol lookup actually works**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478)

```
BeginPackage["aPackage`"]; 
  aTestFunction::usage = "aTestFunction usage"; (*1*)
Begin["`Private`"];
  Remove[aTestFunction]; (*2*)
  aTestFunction[arg_] := arg + 1; (*3*)
  Protect[aTestFunction];
End[];
EndPackage;
```

---

```
? aTestFunction
```

> Information::notfound: Symbol aTestFunction not found. >>

---

```
? aPackage`Private`aTestFunction
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your reply ! It's all clear now. I think that my oversight was in leaving behind that `usage` command is totally different from a simple string assignment.

Comment: @AlbertRetey ok, let's. Thanks for help.