# Why is my MMA package unable to evaluate some user-defined functions?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, packages

I am trying to create a package for other Mathematica programmers to use, but in doing so, I came across an interesting MMA problem which I cannot seem to figure out.

The following code in .nb file works perfectly fine:

```
FNplot[f_, {xmin_, xmax_, {xname_String, xunit_String}}, {ymin_, ymax_, 
    {yname_String, yunit_String}}] := (
  If[ValueQ[yInt] == False, yInt = {ymin, ymax};];
  If[ValueQ[xInt] == False, xInt = {xmin, xmax};];
  opt = {PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesLabel -> {xunit, yunit}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, Exclusions -> False}; 
Manipulate[
  Plot[f, {t, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> 
    If[ValueQ[xInt] == False || ValueQ[yInt] == False, 
      {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, {xInt, yInt}], Evaluate[opt]],
  {{yInt, {ymin, ymax}, Row[{Spacer[20], Column[StringSplit[yname],
    Center]}]}, ymin, ymax, ControlType -> IntervalSlider, 
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Vertical"}, Method -> "Stop",
    MinIntervalSize -> 0.001, ImageSize -> {25, 300}},
  {{xInt, {xmin, xmax}, Row[{Spacer[125], xname}]}, xmin, xmax, 
    ControlType -> IntervalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled",
    Method -> "Stop", MinIntervalSize -> 0.001, ImageSize -> {300, 25}},
  ControlPlacement -> {Left, Bottom}, LocalizeVariables -> False])

FNdsin[f_, vp_, \[Phi]_, d_, swt_, ct_, nct_, t_] := (s2[n_, T_] := 
    vp*Sin[2*Pi*f*(T - d - (n - 1)*ct) + Pi/180*\[Phi]];
  s[n_, T_] := {s2[n, T], d + (n - 1)*ct < T < d + (n - 1)*ct + swt};
  Piecewise[Table[s[k, t], {k, 1, nct}]])

f = 1; vp = 1; \[Phi] = 90; d = 0.2; swt = 8; ct = 8.5; nct = 4;
FNplot[FNdsin[f, vp, \[Phi], d, swt, ct, nct, t], {0, 32, 
  {"Time Interval", "\[Mu]s"}}, {-1, 1, {"Voltage Interval", "V"}}]
```

However, when I try to put these functions in a .wl file, evaluating the same codes returns an empty plot with the sliders functioning properly.  I have included a `BeginPackage[]`, `Begin["Private"]` (with tilde symbol after `Private`), `End[]`, and `EndPackage[]`.

How can I fix this and why does this happen? I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: I think it is the same problem as here: [Derivative in my package return 0](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478) You have `Plot` with ``MyPackage`Private`t`` and then user enters ``Global`t``. p.s. double \`\` escapes single \` from e.g. ``Global` ``.

Comment: Hello @Kuba, thank you so much for your response. Your response to the problem linked also helped me figure out my mistake. Thank you and my apologies for asking a duplicate question.