# Function working in command line session but not in package

Tags: functions, function-construction, packages

I have this pretty straight-forward function

```
GetMinimum[function_, xmin_] := First[FindMinimum[{function, x>xmin}, x]]
```

that works perfectly within a Mathematica command line session. However after moving that code into a package and calling it like

```
GetMinimum[x^2, -20]
```

I get the following output:

```
{y=x^2, UniversalPlot`Private`x$515 > -20}
```

where UniversalPlot is the name of the package. I cannot figure out how to make the function work when defining it in the package. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478 let me know if you disagree with closing. Or if there are any doubts.

Comment: Actually I don't understand how to apply the answer to the linked question to solve my problem.

Comment: e.g `GetMinimum[function_, {x_, xmin_}] := First[FindMinimum[{function, x>xmin}, x]]`?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way for the caller to *not* pass an additional variable from the outside?

Comment: I've outlined 4 ways in the linked topic. But passing them explicitly seems to be a standard