# function from .wl produces no output

Tags: functions, scoping

I'm trying to learn to reuse functions. I have created a .wl file with 
the following content. As I understand the last line without semicolon is 
the function output. Should each function have it's own block of `Begin[]`
and `End[]`?

```
BeginPackage["vectorFunctions`"]

Begin["`Private`"] (* Begin Private Context *) 

vectorDeriv::usage="
vectorDeriv[v_,bc_Integer]
";
(* The function works fine if declared in the notebook. *)
vectorDeriv[v_,bc_Integer] := 
(
vFFirstDer = D[v,{t}];
vFSecondDer = D[v, {t,2}];
vFFirstDerNorm = N[Norm[vFFirstDer] /. t -> bc];
vFSecondDerNorm = N[Norm[vFSecondDer] /. t -> bc];
{vFFirstDer, vFSecondDer, vFFirstDerNorm, vFSecondDerNorm}
)
End[] (* End Private Context *)
EndPackage[]
```

When I try to call the function from the notebook  I get no output.

```
 (* the path is correct *)
In[39]:= Get["C:\\Program Files \
(x86)\\MyJournal\\Images\\Math_Physics_Library\\vectorFunctions.wl"]

Out[39]= "vectorFunctions`Private`"

In[40]:= vF = {Sin[2 t], E^(3 t), t^3 - 4 t};

In[41]:= vectorDeriv[{Sin[2 t], E^(3 t), -4 t + t^3}, 2]

Out[41]= vectorDeriv[{Sin[2 t], E^(3 t), -4 t + t^3}, 2]
```

Am I missing something with the Private vs Public scope?
Should modules be kept in only Mathematica's running directory?

Comment: You do not need to create a package with `BeginPackage` etc. to simply re-use function definitions.  It is sufficient to put the definitions into an `.m` or `.wl` file and load them with `Get`.  `Get` just evaluates whatever is in your file—it does nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Can you format the question for readability?  You have already asked many questions on StackExchage, so I am sure you are familiar with how to do this.

Comment: If you are asking how to create proper packages (not just re-use a few definitions), then it is a duplicate of [(29324)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/12).

Comment: It does not allow me to edit, It asks for more explanations. If I add more it still does not allow me to change. I

Comment: Code must be indented by precisely 4 spaces. Normal text (not code) *must not* be indented. I noticed that despite having asked 25 questions, many of your posts suffer from formatting problems. If you have a vision (or other) impairment that prevents you from formatting posts, it is best to state this and ask for help, and someone will clean up the formatting. Otherwise, I expect any future posts like this to attract a few downvotes ...

Comment: The problem is that `vectorDeriv` is not mentioned between `BeginPackage` and `Begin`.  See the post about creating packages I linked above (also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132960/12)).

Comment: Another problem will be: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478