# Import expression for function definition inside a Module of a Package

Tags: import, packages, scoping

I've been struggling on this problem for quite a while, but I still don't understand why Mathematica is unable to recognize a function definition where the *rhs* is an `Import` command.

Let me introduce the problem.

Consider the following *Mathematica* Package

```
(*Package v1*)
BeginPackage["test`"]

testFun::usage = "testFun[]";

Begin["`Private`"]

packageDirectory = $InputFileName // DirectoryName;

fModule[] := Module[{},
    f[x_] = Import[FileNameJoin[{packageDirectory,"fun.m"}]];
];

testFun[xx_] := Module[{},
    fModule[];
    Table[f[i], {i, xx}]
];

End[] (* `Private` *)

EndPackage[]
```

where the file `fun.m` acts as simple container for the definition of the body of `f`, e.g.

```
x^2
```

When `testFun[5]` is called in *Mathematica* Notebook the result is

```
{x^2, x^2, x^2, x^2, x^2}
```

which means that the pattern `x_` is not recognized when `fModule[]` is called.

The weird fact is that moving the defintion of `f[x]` *outside* the module, i.e. like

```
(*Package v2*)
BeginPackage["test`"]

testFun::usage = "testFun[]";

Begin["`Private`"]

packageDirectory = $InputFileName // DirectoryName;

f[x_] = Import[FileNameJoin[{packageDirectory,"fun.m"}]];

fModule[] := Module[{},
    f[x_] = Import[FileNameJoin[{packageDirectory,"fun.m"}]];
];

testFun[xx_] := Module[{},
    (*fModule[];*)
    Table[f[i], {i, xx}]
];

End[] (* `Private` *)

EndPackage[]
```

the definition of `f[x]` *is properly recognized*!

Also, everything works if I run the code (Package v1) directly in the FrontEnd!

In my actual code I need the definition of `f[x]` to happen **inside** the module using the `Import`. 
That's because the expression to be used in the definition is quite big and I prefer to keep it in a dedicated `.m` file.

Does anyone know why I can't define a function using an `Import` inside a module? Again, the problem exist in the Package only.

Thanks a lot in advance, and happy new year! :)

Ps: I apologize for the criptic title.

Comment: Look at the output of ```?? test`Private`f``` - you'll see that the `x` returned from `Import` is not in the same context as `f`

Comment: Hi Jason! You're right, the output shows that they are not in the same context: `test\`Private\`f[test\`Private\`x_]=x^2`.

Comment: The problem is that when you finally call `testFun`, you are no longer in the ```test`Private` ``` context, you are now in the global context.  A quick fix is to modify the body of `fModule` to use ```f[ Global`x_] = .... ```.  This assumes that when you actually call `testFun` you will be in the global context.  Someone else will have to provide a more robust solution.

Comment: Better may be to call `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` inside the `Module`. As an aside, using `Module[{}, ...]` is less efficient than just using `(...)`. You're not using `Module` for scoping so you can drop it.

Comment: @JasonB. thanks for the quick fix, I'll try it on my code soon! 
@b3m2a1 the Package `test` is just an example to explain the problem, in my code I really need `Module` because I have several local variables.

Comment: Hi @JasonB.! I tried the quick fix on the "test code" and it worked. Unfortunately I can't say the same for my code, even though they are conceptually the same to my eyes. 
In my code the output of `??test\`Private\`f` shows the parameter `x$` instead of `x`...

Comment: What do we know about `fun.m` file? Is symbol representing "function variable" always "lexically present" in (last) expression in the file, or can it appear dynamically during evaluation of this expression? Are all occurrences of this symbol always written in short form, without any context?

Comment: @jkuczm thanks for your comment! For all intended purposes the fun.m file contains an expression in the variable `x` (actually a list) e.g. `{Sin[x], Exp[x^2], Tan[x-Log[x]]}`. So no context is specified for `x`, right?

Comment: Closely related: [Derivative from my package function returns 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as stated in the comments, is that when you define `fModule` in the private context of your package,

```
fModule[] := Module[{},
    f[x_] = Import[FileNameJoin[{packageDirectory,"fun.m"}]];
];
```

The `x` symbol will have the `FullForm`

```
Pattern[test`Private`x,Blank[]]
```

but since the file `fun.m` is read in when the function is called, the `x` present in that file is parsed as `` Global`x `` (or another context depending on when you call the function).

A hack to get it to work would be to redefine the `f` function to be of the form `` f[Global`x_] ``, but this is not robust since you could be calling the function from within another package.

A better workaround is to define `f` as a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), rather than a symbol with [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).  In `test.m`, use

```
fModule[] := Module[{},
    f = Import[FileNameJoin[{packageDirectory,"fun.m"}]];
];
```

then modify the `fun.m` function to be

```
Function[ x, 
    x^2
]
```

This ensures that `x` is scoped correctly regardless of context.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason! I'll try this as soon as I get access to my computer. 

Comment: Using `Function[{x}, ...]` inside `fun.m` everything works! Again thanks a lot @JasonB.