# Converting strings to expressions in a package

Tags: evaluation, packages, scoping

I have a function that generates an equation in the form of a String.  I want to be able to turn that string into an Expression, and evaluate it in another function.  For example:

```
eqs = "aval + 3.0 bval + kvec[[3]]";

Eval[eqs_, a_, b_, k_List] := 
  Module[{ans},
    ans = Evaluate[ToExpression[eqs] /. {aval -> a, bval -> b, kvec -> k}];
    Return[ans];
];
```

When I run the following, everything works fine.

```
MyEval[eqs, 1, 2, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> 10.
> ```

The problem is, I want `MyEval` to be part of a package.  So for example,

```
BeginPackage["MyDumbTest`"]

MyEval::usage = "This is a dumb test."

Begin["`Private`"];

MyEval[eqs_, a_, b_, k_List] := 
  Module[{ans},
    ans = Evaluate[ToExpression[eqs] /. {aval -> a, bval -> b, kvec -> k}];
    Return[ans];
];

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

The function doesn't work:

```
Quit[]
<<`MyDumbTest

eqs = "aval + 3.0 bval + kvec[[3]]";
MyEval[eqs, 1, 2, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> aval + 3. bval + kvec[[3]]

However, if after loading the package I open the package file (MyDumbTest.m) and execute (shift-return) the cell for `MyEval`,  the command starts working in the notebook, and will work for the remainder of the kernel operation.  Why does this happen and is there a way around it?

Comment: at least closely related: [Derivative from my package function returns 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to discussion in [Derivative from my package function returns 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478), which I highly recommend to read, you can do a little bit of string manipulation for this particular case:

```
(*...*)

MyEval[eqs_, a_, b_, k_List] := Module[{ vars = {"aval", "bval", "kvec"} }
, ToExpression[
    StringTemplate["Function[``, ``]"][vars, eqs]
  ][a, b, k]
]

(* ...*)
```

```
MyEval["aval + 3.0 bval + kvec[[3]]", 1, 2, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> 10.

```
BeginPackage["test`"];
Needs["MyDumbTest`"];

MyEval["aval + 3.0 bval + kvec[[3]]", 1, 2, {1, 2, 3}]

EndPackage[];
```

> 10.

The second example will not work with solutions from other answers.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I understand why that happens.  Thanks for the coding advice too.

Comment: @KenThomson great, [take a tour then](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).