# Transferring a function between two modules in a package

Tags: packages, scoping

I have a first module which  outputs as forth output a function G  I want to transfer to another module. The specific function is

```
G = (72 (97 + 57 s))/(55 (55 + 96 s + 36 s^2))
```

Everything works before encapsulating.  Here's a short version of the first  module:

```
Rat[expr_, expc_, csi_: 1] :=
  (* Fq is defined outside, hopefully global variable *)
  Module[{nCLroots, nphases, sct, sc, ks, kss, kp, G, Gp, WE, WEp},
    nCLroots = Length[expr];
    nphases = Length[expc];
    ϕ =
      Product[(1 + #/expc[[i]]), {i, nphases}] /
       Product[(1 + #/expr[[i]]), {i, nCLroots}] &;
    rhmin =
      1 - Simplify[
            Product[expr[[i]], {i, nCLroots}] / 
            Product[expc[[i]], {i, nphases}]];
    Print["input: ", Subscript[ϕ, "-"], " = ", ϕ[s], " q =", q = Fq csi (1 - rhmin)];
    sct = Apart[Simplify[ϕ[#]/(csi (1 - rhmin) (# - Fq))], #] &;
    (* k - q *) kss = ((1/sct[#]) + csi (1 - rhmin) Fq) &;
    (* symbol, without q *);
    ks = Apart[kss[#], #] &;
    Print["symbol k = ", ks[s]];
    kp = D[ks[s], s] /. s -> Fq;
    WEp = FullSimplify[1/((ks[s] /. s -> # + Fq) - q)] &;
    WE = Function[s, WEp[s]];
    Gp = FullSimplify[1/(# kp) - WEp[#]] &;
    G = Function[s, Gp[s]];
    Print["WE = ", Factor[WE[s]]];
    Print["G = ", Factor[G[s]]];
    {ϕ, rhmin, ks, G}];
```

The following code works

```
exr = {1/2, 3/2}; 
exc = {1, 2};
Fq = 1/3; 
cc = Rat[exr, exc];
G = cc[[4]][x]
Print[" G=", G]
```

but stops working when I encapsulate the modules in a Mathematica package and I guess it's because the way I transfer `G`

The structure of the RatC.wl package encapsulating the modules is

```
BeginPackage["RatC`"]
Unprotect @@ Names["RatC`*"];
ClearAll @@ Names["RatC`*"];
Rat::usage="..."
Begin["`Private`"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Copy-paste of Rat above
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

after encapsulation, the function `G`   contains two `Private` variables and sends the second module into very long computations.

```
G =
 1/
   ((1/2 - 1/(6 (1 + RatC`Private`Fq)^2) - 
       7/(8 (2 + RatC`Private`Fq)^2)) RatC`Private`s) -
  1 / 
   (-(2/3) + (RatC`Private`Fq + RatC`Private`s)/2 +
     1/(6 (1 + RatC`Private`Fq + RatC`Private`s)) +
     7/(8 (2 + RatC`Private`Fq + RatC`Private`s)))
```

The existence of two `Private` variables seemed to me to be significant, since functions with just one `Private` seemed to be usable just by plugging s; I wanted to make Fq a global variable by defining it outside the package, but G has still two `Private` variables

Any recommendations? Is it easier to transfer G as expression than as pure function?

Comment: I understood your "modules" to be packages by themselves, so I updated the question for clarity.

Comment: At least closely related: [114769](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're doing exactly. Some of the things that I don't understand: How does a package output a package? How do you transfer that to a module (and what is a module here)? How is what you're giving a function (that's just an expression)? How do you encapsulate the packages? Is a "Mathematica package" the same thing as a "package"? What does "sometimes accepted and sometimes not" mean? What happens in both cases? Please provide the full relevant code of your files, together with the necessary package directory structure to *fully* reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your `G` is not a function but an expression. To use it elsewhere, consider returning a proper `Function` instead, such as `G = Function[s, (72 (97 + 57 s))/(55 (55 + 96 s + 36 s^2))]`. This way the dependent parameter is encapsulated and you will not have to deal with context issues like the one you're seeing here.

Comment: We need to have the code for both modules and anything else that is defined in your package to be able answer this question.

Comment: I prepared a short version of module which defines G.