# Why a script stops working when moved from the beginning of a file into a package?

Tags: packages

Here's a two command script defining L1, Der1 (which compute the first Lyapunov exponent of an ODE):

```
Subscript[L, 1] = 
 Subscript[F, 3, 0] + Subscript[F, 1, 2] + Subscript[G, 0, 3] + 
  Subscript[G, 2, 1] + 
  1/\[Omega] (Subscript[F, 1, 
      1] (Subscript[F, 2, 0] + Subscript[F, 0, 2]) - 
     Subscript[G, 1, 1] (Subscript[G, 2, 0] + Subscript[G, 0, 2]) + 
     Subscript[F, 0, 2] Subscript[G, 0, 2] - 
     Subscript[F, 2, 0] Subscript[G, 2, 0]); 
Der1[fg_, equilibrium_ : {}] := 
 Module[{J, xyshift, T, Tinvuv, FG, derivatives, a, b, u, v, i, j},
  J = Simplify[D[fg, {{x, y}}] /. equilibrium];
  xyshift = {x -> x + (x /. equilibrium), y -> y + (y /. equilibrium)};
  T = {{1, 0}, {-a/\[Omega], -b/\[Omega]}};
  Tinvuv = Inverse[T] . {u, v};
  FG = (T . fg /. xyshift) /. {x -> Tinvuv[[1]], 
      y -> Tinvuv[[2]]} /. {a -> J[[1, 1]], b -> J[[1, 2]]};
  derivatives = {};
  For[i = 0, i <= 3, i++, For[j = 0, j <= 3 - i, j++, 
    derivatives = 
     Join[derivatives, {Subscript[F, i, 
        j] -> (D[FG[[1]], {u, i}, {v, j}] /. {u -> 0, v -> 0}), 
       Subscript[G, i, 
        j] -> (D[FG[[2]], {u, i}, {v, j}] /. {u -> 0, v -> 0})}]]];
  derivatives];
```

It works fine:

```
fg = Subscript[\[Kappa], 1] x^2 {1, 0} + 
   Subscript[\[Kappa], 2] x y {-1, 1} + 
   Subscript[\[Kappa], 3] y {0, -1} + Subscript[\[Kappa], 4] y {1, -1};
derivatives = Simplify[Der1[fg]]
L1 = Simplify[Subscript[L, 1] /. derivatives]
```

Then I copied Der1, but not L1,  into a package util, after Begin["`Private`"], I only changed its name to DerS, and the same commands don't work anymore. The derivatives yield now

```
{Subscript[util`Private`F, 0, 0] -> 
  x^2 Subscript[\[Kappa], 1] + 
   y (-x Subscript[\[Kappa], 2] + Subscript[\[Kappa], 3]), 
 Subscript[util`Private`G, 0, 0] -> 0
```

...  and are not subsituted in L1  at all (the input formula of L1 is offered as answer, with no substitution).  I could still try to include the L1 formula to the script in the package, but first I'm curious if this can be avoided.

Comment: You'd get more attention with a minimal example and a short package snippet. Without that I can suggest [114769](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478) which feels like the issue you are facing.

Comment: My problem was precisely that the script returned 0, as in the question above  114769, so thanks!