# Where should global variables be defined in a package?

Tags: programming, packages

I am trying to understand two of the answers to the question 114769 [Package functions and symbolic calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114769/package-functions-and-symbolic-calculations)

```
    ClearAll["MyP`*"];

BeginPackage["MyP`"];
Global`b;
MyLagrange;

Begin["`Private`"];

MyLagrange[f_, var_] := Module[{a}, a = D[f, var] + b;
   a];

End[];
EndPackage[];

b = 17; MyLagrange[Sin[x1], x1]
```

returns

```
MyP`Private`b + Cos[x1]
```

so the Global statement has been ignored

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could explicitly use `` Global`b `` in the definition of `MyLagrange`:

```
ClearAll["MyP`*"];

BeginPackage["MyP`"];
MyLagrange;

Begin["`Private`"];

MyLagrange[f_, var_] := Module[{a}, a = D[f, var] + Global`b; a];

End[];
EndPackage[];

b = 17; MyLagrange[Sin[x1], x1]
(* 17 + Cos[x1] *)
```