# Using Begin to return to a previously defined context

Tags: contexts

I am trying to understand how contexts in Mathematica work. Suppose I want to write a block of code in which all newly defined symbols are in a particular context.

If I input the following code

```
Begin["test`"];
Context[]
a=2;
a
End[];
Context[]
a
```

then I get output

```
test`a
2
Global`
a
```

as I would expect. I can also type

```
test`a
```

which outputs

```
2
```

But what I don't understand is why next inputting

```
Begin["test`"];
Context[]
a
```

produces output

```
test`
a
```

The `` Begin["test`"]; `` line has shifted the context back to `` test` ``, so why does inputting `a` produce output `a` and not output `2`?

---

**Edit**: I don't understand why this is a duplicate of [Result about Context is inconsistent with the description of “Power Programming with Mathematica”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/result-about-context-is-inconsistent-with-the-description-of-power-programming). In that question, the symbol is assigned a value in both the local and global context. In my example I only assign a value to `a` in the `test` context.

Comment: Because `$ContextPath` is searched before `$Context` and there is already `a` in ``Global` ``.

Comment: Ad Edit: The question is not the same but the answer is. "When you enter a symbol name such as `x`, MMA will check if a symbol already exists.[...]  If not, then it will create a new symbol named `x` in `$Context`.". And you did this at the end of the first code block.

Comment: Shortly, symbols are created just by mentioning them, no values are needed.