# Is the package documentation buggy?

Tags: packages, core-language, documentation, contexts

At https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html we read:

```
BeginPackage["Package`"]
```

> set Package` to be the current context, and
>   put only System` on the context search path

But Package` is also put on the context search path.  (In fact, this is illustrated in the documentation for `BeginPackage`.)

At https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html we read

> \$ContextPath is a global variable that gives a list of contexts, 
>   after \$Context, to search in trying to find a symbol that has been entered.

But `$ContextPath` is searched *before* $Context.

Am I misunderstanding something?

**Edit:** Szabolcs points out the the second of these two documentation bugs in an answer to a different question, at [Result about Context is inconsistent with the description of “Power Programming with Mathematica”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/result-about-context-is-inconsistent-with-the-description-of-power-programming)

Comment: Yes, it's buggy. As you can see, it was reported three years ago, and it is still unfixed. Isn't that annoying?  If you report it too, there is a higher chance that it will finally be corrected. There is a Give Feedback link at the end of every online doc page.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks.  I reported both problems using the Give Feedback links.