# Using Print inside of function FindRoot

Tags: functions

Below is an example from *Power programming with Mathematica* by David Wagner.
The example is implemented in *Mathematica 3*.

> The sequence of iterates that are generated by FindRoot's internal
>   algorithm can be printed using the following technique:
>
> [image]

I did exactly as the one above with *Mathematica 10.4* but couldn't get the result as above. 
Here is what I got:

```
FindRoot[Print[x];Sin[x]-Cos[x],{x,.5}]
```

> `x`
>
> `{x->0.785398}`

Can anyone help me do the same with *Mathematica 10.4*?

Comment: Hm... Wagner's book was written a long time ago. Seams that things have changed a bit. I recently encountered another issue regarding context & context search (Chapter 8.1.1) which might be closely related to your problem. The explanation in the book is different than in Mathematica documentation. Nevertheless, it goes against encapsulation that you could just like that gain insights into internal operation of `FindRoot`. I'm also interested in to hear opinion of more experienced users.

Comment: @ercegovac As to the context issue, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StepMonitor option seems to work as expected.

```
In[3]:= FindRoot[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, 0.5}, StepMonitor :> Print[x]]

During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.793408

During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398

During evaluation of In[3]:= 0.785398

Out[3]= {x -> 0.785398}
```

Although this does not print the initial value of x as 0.5