# What is the accessibility of a package's `Private` context variables?

Tags: packages, core-language, scoping, contexts

I've been reading up on how Mathematica handles contexts, `$Context`, `$ContextPath`, and a few of the tutorials they have on Packages.

What I'm wondering about is how the functions defined in, say, `` CustomPackage` `` are able to access the variables in `` CustomPackage`Private` ``.

For example,

```
BeginPackage["CustomPackage`"]

MyFunction::usage = "MyFunction[arg1] adds 5 to arg1."

Begin["`Private`"]

abc=5;
MyFunction[arg1_] := arg1 + abc;

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

When I load the package `` <<CustomPackage` `` the `$ContextPath` will have `` CustomPackage` `` on it, but not `` CustomPackage`Private` ``

So how does `MyFunction` know the value of `abc` at the delayed function call (when it is called) if the `` Private` `` context isn't on the `$ContextPath`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So how does `MyFunction` know the value of `abc` at the delayed function call (when it is called) if the  `` Private` `` context isn't on the `$ContextPath`

There is a misunderstanding here.  You are assuming that `abc` is searched for in some context only when `MyFunction[something]` is evaluated.  This is not the case.

`$Context` and `$ContextPath` only affect how source code is *parsed* (not how expressions are *evaluated*). In other words, they only affect how the text you write in the package file is interpreted and converted into in-memory expressions. Once the package has been loaded with `Get`, this interpretation has already happened.  `MyFunction` has been interpreted as the symbol `` CustomPackage`MyFunction `` and `abc` has been interpreted as `` CustomPackage`Private`abc ``, [according to the value of `$Context` and `$ContextPath`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12) at the time each was read.  These are the full names of these symbols and this is how they exist in memory.

Load the package and try this:

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
 Print@Definition[MyFunction]
]
```

You'll see the following printed:

```
CustomPackage`MyFunction[CustomPackage`Private`arg1_] := 
  CustomPackage`Private`arg1+CustomPackage`Private`abc
```

As you can see, a context is always associated with every symbol.

Answer (score 7):

All symbols are created at load time, so when you do:

```
BeginPackage["X`"];

x::usage="Declaring x as an exported symbol in the X` context";

Begin["`SomePrivateContext`"];

x[a_]:=b

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

`x` was created as `` X`x `` but the `DownValues` of `x` reference `` X`SomePrivateContext`a `` and `` X`SomePrivateContext`b `` which were created at the time the function was defined. These symbols are unique, so that reference only ever points that a single object.

Answer (score 7):

`` Begin["`Private`"]; `` sets the current `$Context` to `` "CustomPackage `Private`" ``. This causes two things:

- The symbol `abc` will be searched in the current context first, thus in`` "CustomPackage`Private`" ``. Only if it is not found there, the search goes on along `$ContextPath`.
- If no matching symbol is found this way, a new symbol `abc` is created, namely in the current `$Context` which is `` "CustomPackage`Private`" ``. So the full symbol name is `` "CustomPackage`Private`abc" ``.

For example, running your code in a fresh kernel and executing

```
??MyFunction
```

reveals that the full definition of `MyFunction` is

> `` MyFunction[CustomPackage`Private`arg1_]:=CustomPackage`Private`arg1+CustomPackage`Private`abc ``

Moreover, with

```
 ?*`abc
```

you see that the only symbol in all contexts that matches `abc` is `` CustomPackage`Private`abc `` and has the value `5` assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

> So how does MyFunction know the value of abc
>       at the delayed function call (when it is called)
>       if the Private` context isn't on the $ContextPath?

because `` "CustomPackage`Private`" `` is the value of `$Context` when `MyFunction` is defined (i.e. it is not just `$ContextPath` that determines what a function sees but *also* what is on `$Context`).

---

**TL:DR**

This is a timely question because it indirectly touches upon the competing imperatives of developers and end-users. To the question itself:

The whole point of packages is that they are a form of encapsulation that allows developers to, without interferance, implement functionality for end-users without bothering them with the underlying details. In particular, the encapsulation involves controlling namespaces so that the underlying details can involve symbols that help implement the functionality but ultimately don't end-up polluting a user's namespace.  All symbols defined in a `` "*`Private`" `` namespace are created for exactly this purpose.

Hence in the OP's example, the variable `abc` is an underlying detail for the implementation of the public `MyFunction`. The developer needs the "detail" of `abc` but this particular symbol is of no direct interest to an end-user who typically just ends up calling `MyFunction[]`.

The package layout achieves this encapsulation by manipulating `$ContextPath` and `$Context` as the control-flow passes through the package when it is first loaded. This is described in the other answers and documentation but it can be useful to see it directly:

```
loc[n_] := Sow[<|
                 "Location" -> n,
                 "$Context" -> $Context, 
                 "$ContextPath" -> $ContextPath|>];

  Reap[

   loc@1;

   BeginPackage["CustomPackage`"];

   loc@2;

   MyFunction::usage = "MyFunction[arg1] adds 5 to arg1.";

   Begin["`Private`"];

   loc@3;

   abc = 5;
   MyFunction[arg1_] := arg1 + abc;

   End[];

   loc@4;

   EndPackage[];

   loc@5
   ]// Last // Dataset
```

[image]

> When I load the package <the $ContextPath will have CustomPackage on it, but not CustomPackage`Private`

Yes, this implements both the public exporting of all `CustomPackage` functions but without polluting end-users namespaces with implementation details. In code around Location 3, all packages are cleared out thereby eliminating possible conflicts with existing `abc` definitions in currently loaded packages. This is encapsulation benefitting developers but the encapsulation benefitting end-users, as observed, is that on exiting (at Location 5) `$ContextPath` contains `` "CustomPackage`" `` (to provide access to `MyFunction`) but *not* `` "CustomPackage`Private`" `` thereby shielding users from symbols used in `MyFunction`'s implementation.

A programmatic confirmation at Location 5 gives:

```
{MemberQ["CustomPackage`"]@$ContextPath, 
 MemberQ["CustomPackage`Private`"]@$ContextPath,
 Context["abc"]}

 {True, False, "Global`"}
```

At Location 3 in the control-flow, the symbol `abc` is not contained in any of the contexts defined in `$ContextPath`, (`` "CustomPackage`" ``, or `` "System`" ``) nor is it (yet) in the context defined in `$Context` (`` "CustomPackage`Private`" ``). Consequently, the name `abc` gets created in the context currently set to `$Context`. At this location `$Context` has value `` "CustomPackage`Private`" `` and hence the symbol `` CustomPackage`Private`abc `` is created. When the control flow then moves on to `MyFunction[]`, `` "CustomPackage`Private`" `` is still the value of `$Context` so this function "sees" `abc` (hence it not just `$ContextPath` that determines what a function sees but what is on both`$ContextPath` *and* `$Context`).

Note how the convention of placing usage definitions at Location 2 is ostensibly for documentation purposes but its more important role is to ensure that the function goes into the package's context (see `$Context` at Location 2) before subsequently being made available in the implementation and for end-users (see `$ContextPath` at Locations 3 and 5).

IMO it is kind of cool how these placement protocols just work intuitively without necessarily keeping front-of-mind all the control-flow manipulations, variable-creation mechanisms etc taking place behind the scenes. Hence this means being very careful changing the framework but also IMHO the time is ripe for such extensions given that the line between users/developers may well be in the process of blurring.