# How to hide functions in a sub package from user level?

Tags: packages

The only packages I did before were simple one file packages.

I am now learning how to make a package that has a sub package. The main package calls functions in the subpackage. But user is not supposed to be able to call functions directly in the subpackage.

Here is an example below. I need to have the subpackage in *separate* file, so I can't sub package code in the private part of the main package, at least I do not know how to.

What Am I doing wrong in the following? Under

```
 C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications
```

I have

```
Applications/
   mypkg/
      Kernel/
         init.m
      mypkg.m
      sub.m
```

init.m is

```
 Get ["mypkg`mypkg`"]
 Get ["mypkg`sub`"]
```

mypkg.m is

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`"]
main::usage="main[]"
Begin["`Private`"]
main[]:=Module[{},  
  mypkg`sub`foo[1]
]
End[] (* End Private Context *)
EndPackage[]
```

And sub.m is

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`sub`"]
Begin["`Private`"]
  foo[n_]:=Module[{},
     Print["in mypkg`sub`foo[]"];
     n+1
  ]
End[] (* End Private Context *)
EndPackage[]
```

But now in my notebook, I find I am able to call

```
 mypkg`sub`foo[]
```

How is this possible? Since `foo` has no `foo::usage` entry to export it to outside and it is in the private context of sub?

```
<< mypkg`
mypkg`sub`foo[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want only functions in `mypkg.m` to be able to call functions in `sub.m`. What to fix in the above code for this to happen?

I am finding working with packages with multiple files in Mathematica confusing so far, as it is not clear how to separate scope of things.

V12.

Comment: You can ``Needs["mypkg`sub`"]`` after `BeginPackage` of the main package. Or have nested `BeginPackages` if all of them export to your common context. There is a lot of discussion in [**176434**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176434/5478) but I think that thread misses simple approach. Start reading from Ronald Monson answer, then b3m2a1's and then the rest.

Comment: Note that you will not be able to prevent the user from calling a function using its full name, e.g. ``mypkg`sub`private`foo[1]`` will always work. As for your problem: I think the problem is the following: You first `Get` ``mypkg`mypkg``, which declares the symbol ``mypkg`sub`foo``. After this, you `Get` ``mypkg`sub``, which now sees this symbol on the `$ContextPath`, which is why the definition inside the ``Private` `` context is still attached to the "public" symbol. In short, your exporting statement is the call in ``mypkg` ``.

Comment: Nasser, what @LukasLang states is correct, I find it analogous to the way in which we are able to call undocumented functions such as ones directly to the systems or otherwise. I usually wrap my overarching functions in an option defining wrapper, this allows me to bundle a number of them together for the functionality you wish to receive. However, I, too, have only used single package files, and am only beginning to investigate the multiple package method.

Comment: For which purpose do you want to hide these symbols?

Comment: @Shadowray `For which purpose do you want to hide these symbols?` that is the whole purpose of data and implementation hiding. So that your are free to modify them later as you wish without breaking client code. If Client to your package had access to your package private data and functions, and written code based on these, then if you later change the private data or the private functions API, then the client application will no longer work when you release new version of the package.

Comment: @Nasser I think the convention is typically that everything in a ``Private` `` context is considered undocumented and an implementation detail. If someone still decides to use it, they should know what they're getting themselves into. The nice thing about this approach is that you can still modify/use anything to your liking if you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica does not have a concept of private symbols in the sense of most other programming languages. Given its full name, you can call any function, assuming it has been loaded. However, there is still a scoping mechanism available to us: `Contexts` and `$ContextPath`. In short, every symbol lives in a context (see [`Context`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html)). If a symbol without a explicit context is encountered, the following happens (see e.g. @Szabolcs' answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/what-is-the-accessibility-of-a-packages-private-context-variables)):

- If the symbol exists in `$Context`, this one is taken
- All contexts on `$ContextPath` are searched in order (sub-contexts not included). If a symbol with the right name is found, this one is taken
- If the symbol is not in any of these contexts, a new symbol is defined in the current context (see [`$Context`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Context.html))

This means that we can hide symbols by not adding their context to `$ContextPath`. This is what is usually done with `` Begin["`Private`"] ``:

- `` BeginPackage["foo`"] `` sets `$Context` to `` "foo`" ``, and `$ContextPath` to `` {"foo`","System`"} ``. Any symbol that is encountered after `BeginPackage` is therefore defined in `` foo` `` (assuming it's not already in `` System` ``).
- `` Begin[`"Private`"] `` sets `$Context` to `` foo`Private` `` but leaves `$ContextPath` alone. So any symbol that is already defined from before is taken, and new symbols are created in the `` foo`Private` `` context.
- `End[]` resets `$Context`
- `EndPackage[]` resets `$Context` and `$ContextPath`, and adds `` "foo`" `` to `$ContextPath`. This means that only symbols that have been encountered before the `` Begin["`Private`"] `` part are directly visible to the user.

Next, I will demonstrate how we can have a package and a sub-package, where the package has access to the "private" symbols of the sub-package. (Note that in most cases, simply putting internal stuff in a private context should be enough)

This is using the same package layout as shown in the question.

**`init.m`**: (if this is the only context of the init file, it can also be omitted)

```
Get["mypkg`mypkg`"]
```

**`mypkg.m`**:

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`"]
Needs["mypkg`sub`"] (* load the sub-packge. Remember that BeginPackage will 
  reset $ContextPath again, so it doesn't appear loaded from the outside *)
AppendTo[$ContextPath,"mypkg`sub`Private`"] (* make the private context visible as well*)
main::usage="main[]"
Begin["`Private`"]
main[]:=Module[{},  
  foo[1] (* since mypkg`sub`Private` is on $ContextPath, we don't need the full name here *)
]
End[] (* End Private Context *)
EndPackage[]
```

**`sub.m`**:

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`sub`"]
Begin["`Private`"]
  foo[n_]:=Module[{},
     Print["in mypkg`sub`Private`foo[]"]; (* this is the actual full name now *)
     n+1
  ]
End[] (* End Private Context *)
EndPackage[]
```

This is how it looks now:

```
<< mypkg`

main[]
(* in mypkg`sub`Private`foo[] *)
(* 2 *)

foo[1] (* foo is not visible *)
(* foo[1] *)

MemberQ[$ContextPath, "mypkg`sub`"] (* sub-packege is not loaded *)
(* False *)

<< mypkg`sub`

foo[1] (* foo is still not visible *)
(* foo[1] *)

MemberQ[$ContextPath, "mypkg`sub`"] (* sub-packege is now loaded *)
(* True *)

mypkg`sub`Private`foo[1] (* the full name will always work *)
(* in mypkg`sub`Private`foo[] *)
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: Well-picked up the subtlety of the observed behaviour in the OP's code but this is a good example of the risks entailed in not following "idiomatic" practice (which admittedly is not documented). It's worth pointing out though that the solution here is non-idiomatic and carries its own risks. For example, potential name conflicts between the two packages. Better IMO would be to follow idiomatic practice and explicitly export `foo` in `mypckg\`sub\`` and use a single `Needs` call in the private context of `mypckg\``

Answer (score 6):

An [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176591/2249) to a similar question regarding package dependencies described the directory structures needed to implement sub-functions but  here the details of the function structure are illustrated. To first backtrack; an ideal package framework should enjoy the following properties with function names inserted from this example but which apply more generally:

1. The end-user's name-space should not be polluted by `foo`.
2. The `` mypkg` `` package  should "see" the unadulterated `foo`
   *without* needing a full context specification.
3. There should be no potential conflicts in `` mypkg` ``and `` mypkg`sub` ``.
4. To seamlessly scale, there should be no need for (multiple) `Needs`'s calls given the introduction of a new "Developer's `DeclarePackage`" idiom.

The OP's implementation satisfies 1) The accepted answer satisfies 1) and 2);  WL's "idiomatic method" (to be illustrated shortly) satisfies 1), 2) and 3);  and finally, I will mention the syntax  for an extended package framework which satisfies 1), 2), 3) &  4).

Explanations for the above claims:

1) An end-user's namespace is not polluted because an unadulterated `foo` (one without full context specification) is still available for use in the end-users environment (`foo`'s full contextual name is `` mypkg`sub`Private`foo `` but `` mypkg`sub`Private` `` doesn't appear on `$ContextPath`).

2) In the OP's  example,  any appearance of the full context form  `` mypkg`sub`foo `` means accessing its definition wherever it is placed but what may initially seem surprising here is that an apparently encapsulated definition has attached itself to an apparently external symbol. Consider however, the following snippet:

```
mypkg`sub`foo

BeginPackage["mypkg`sub`"];
Begin["`Private`"];
foo[n_] := Module[{}, Print["in mypkg`sub`foo[]"];
  n + 1]
End[]; (*End Private Context*)
EndPackage[];

mypkg`sub`foo[1]
```

[image]

One might have expected `foo` to be created (and hence encapsulated) as `` mypkg`sub`Private`foo `` with the final `` mypkg`sub`foo[1] `` remaining unevaluated but a previous creation of the `` mypkg`sub`foo `` symbol (anywhere) ensures that the internal `foo` now instead refers to `` mypkg`sub`foo `` and hence attaches its subsequent definition to this symbol. As noted, this is because `` mypkg`sub` `` remains on `$ContextPath` when the control flow passes through `` Begin["`Private`"] ``  with new symbols only being created (and hence encapsulated) in `` mypkg`sub`Private` `` *if* they *don't* already appear in `$ContextPath`. But we are now, at least, in a position to see *why* the idiomatic practice works:

The idiomatic way to define this sub-package

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`sub`"];
usage::foo = "foo[n] adds one to n";
Begin["`Private`"];
foo[n_] := Module[{}, Print["in mypkg`sub`foo[]"];
  n + 1]
End[]; (*End Private Context*)
EndPackage[];
```

ensures firstly that all symbols created in `foo`'s *definition* are encapsulated in `` mypkg`sub`Private` ``  (and hence don't pollute elsewhere, either in end-users' namespaces or in developers' other package namespaces). In terms of the `foo` symbol itself; it is defined in `` mypkg`sub` `` and hence accessible in the private context given that `` mypkg`sub` `` is the only other context whose symbols the private context "sees" (we will cover `foo`'s exposure shortly). This similarly applies to any other symbols defined in usage commands placed between `` BeginPackage["mypkg`sub`"] ``  and `` Begin["`Private`"] ``;

Hence following idiomatic practice we see that usage commands serve a dual purpose; ostensibly to provide documentation but actually much more importantly, to create the symbols in `` mypkg`sub` `` that are to be seen in the following private context (when being defined) and in other packages (when exported).

For years I used these idioms without giving a second thought to the actual context manipulations occurring behind the scenes that give them effect. It was only when I came to extend this `BeginPackage/EndPackage` framework (to implement (4) described later) that I came to appreciate the superb design that has underpinned their implementation (I'd like to know who came up with it?) over all these years. In fact, IMO this is the very marker and epitome of brilliant language design; end-users do things that just seem natural (place to-be-public symbols in idiomatic positions;  idiomatically wrap to-be-encapsulated code in `Begin`/`End` etc.) while the design takes care of the rest. It does also mean though, that you deviate from designed idioms at your peril.

To be continued ...

Query 1: Why is the accepted answer (satisfying OP's specific request) risky?
Query 2: Why doesn't WL's current package idiom "seamlessly scale"?

Returning to the example at hand, our idiomatic definition of `foo` in `` mypkg`sub` `` has, while encapsulating `foo`'s definitions (in `` mypkg`sub`Private` ``) apparently also made the symbol `foo`  public as it is exported as a symbol from `` mypkg`sub` ``. But therein lies the horns of an apparent dilemma, a tension between the imperatives of end-user and developer--on the one hand, `foo` needs to be private from an an end-users perspective but on the other, public from a developer's perspective in exporting it for servicing the over-arching package `` mypkg` ``. In fact, it is actually this tension that lies at the root of a design challenge, one eventually confronted by all developers.

It is readily met idiomatically (but IMO ultimately unsatisfactorily) by the following practice of internally placing `` Needs["mypkg`"] ``

```
BeginPackage["mypkg`"]
main::usage = "main[]"
Begin["`Private`"]
Needs["mypkg`sub`"];
main[] := foo[1] // moreThanfoo;
End[] (*End Private Context*)
EndPackage[]
```

This "solves" our dilemma because it makes `foo` "temporarily public" in the service of `main`'s definition but then returns `foo` to its encapsulated, private status as the control flow exits `EndPackage[]` in preparation for end-user application. It is natural in the sense of mimicking an interactive session by, in a developer's environment (within the package definitions), making available functionality in the same familiar way `Needs` imports functionality in an interactive session.

Let's see the `Context` manipulation going on behind the scenes to give this effect--`Needs` puts `` mypkg`sub` `` on `$ContextPath` thereby giving access to all of `` mypkg`sub` ``'s exported functions but what `Needs` giveth `EndPackage` taketh as the latter removes `` mypkg`sub` `` from `$ContextPath` and with it end-users access to any of `` mypkg`sub` `` exported symbols as desired.

We can immediately see why this is preferable to the accepted answer and the approach initially tried by the OP: in this idiomatic approach, within `` mypkg` `` only `foo` is exposed from `` mypkg`sub` `` and not any of the symbols involved in `foo`'s definition which is what occurs when  `` mypkg`sub`Private` `` is added to `$ContextPath` as in the accepted answer (Note that `Needs` also ensures the package is a priori loaded in addition to adjusting `$ContextPath` and it turns out that de-coupling this action will key to a new "Developer's `DeclarePackage`").

Now there can be a bit of a trade-off between encapsulation and convenience. For example, I'm [not a big fan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126896/2249) of routinely including helper functions within the body of a `Module`/`Block`/`Let` as I feel that the loss of readability is rarely offset by any (local) encapsulating gains  particularly when backed by the encapsulation still taking place at the package level. Modularization therefore, not only occurs at run-time but also occurs at the code organization level so I prefer to have helper definitions tucked away in other collapsible cells within a package preventing them from clogging up the logic of my main function (but see [other viewpoints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126881/2249) and this is restricted to functions not variables).

I've also never actually stumbled *across* a naming/variable conflict within a single "standard" package/file although of course when mission-critical functionality arises "total encapsulation" can be adopted in a similar way that a helper function can command its own package if it morphes into something more general.

Potential naming conflicts with helper functions/etc *across* packages however, is a very different matter and IMO real risks accrue in scaling a code-base by file encapsulation alone (effectively the approach of the accepted answer) and in particular, without including the context encapsulation provided by fine-grained package disaggregation.

Ok, so the described idiomatic method seems fit-for-purpose, can handle the OP's request for a single subsidiary function, so what about our earlier claim that it doesn't "seamlessly scale"  or that it is in some sense inherently  unsatisfactory. Well, first, this needs to be put in perspective; clearly the idiomatic method is an elegant, bullet-proof and proven base and it evidently *does* scale given the numerous  large, successful packages/systems that have already been built on top of it. Hence for someone starting out in package development you can indeed go a long way before any of the current limitations start to make their presence felt---for most package development therefore, what follows may not be relevant for a considerable amount of time.

Nonetheless, it is nice to at least be aware of the existence of  frameworks for managing the burgeoning complexity that inevitably accompanies  a package's growth, a quest, to which we now turn.

To be continued ... (or not as this is becoming inappropriately saga-like for SE)