# When making a package, how can I make a function that is already used by system?

Tags: functions, packages, system

Obviously, `Plus[a,b]` is given by Mathematica but say I have a package and I want to name a function `Plus[a,b]`. How can I go about making a new function without overwriting the original function `Plus[a,b]` given from System.
I figured it might be something like this:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]

Test`Plus::usage = "Plus[a_,b_] gives..."

(* function defs *)
Test`Plus[a_,b_] := ...

EndPackage[]
```

Or maybe it has something to do with `Unprotect[]`? Ideally, I could still type in `Plus[a,b]` and make use of the system function but I could also type in

```
Test`Plus[a,b]
```

to make use of the  new Plus function from the package.
Thanks

EDIT: in response to  Marius Ladegård Meyer
Is this what you are suggesting I do?

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]

Plus::usage = "asdf"

Begin["`Private`"]
Plus[a_,b_] := adfasf
End[]

EndPackage[]
```

And then I can use Test`Plus?

Comment: I think `Begin/End` and `BeginPackage/EndPackage` are the way to go here. Using `Unprotect` on such a central function as `Plus` is an **extremely bad idea**, since it will modify a _huge_ number of other (behind the scenes) Mathematica functions.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean Begin/End? Like ```Begin["`Private`"]``` or something?

Comment: Yes. Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/HandleShadowingOfSymbolNames.html) Workflow guide?

Comment: So then are you saying this is what I need? (see edit in post)

Comment: I do not actually plan to modify Plus, that was just an example. In my instance I am reading The Mathematica Programmer by Maeder and in chapter 5 his database code uses a lot of functions that have preexisting definitions. The book was written for like Mathematica v 2 so its possible those functions didn't exist back then but I'm pretty certain they must have. Some of the functions he uses in his package are "Tuples", "Select", "Union", "Complement", and many more, all of which have preexisting definitions and likely did back then too

Comment: The best practice here is to call your function something other than `Plus`.

Comment: Functions related to context change in _v3_. You may want to reat this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/1871