# How to understand BeginPackage and Begin properly?

Tags: packages, contexts

Using `Get` to evaluate these three .wl:

First:

```
BeginPackage["Functions`"]
S1=1;
Begin["`Test1`"]
K1=2;
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Second:

```
BeginPackage["Functions`"]
S1=1;
Begin["Test1`"]
K1=2;
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Third:

```
BeginPackage["Functions`"]    
S1=1;    
Begin["`Test1`"]    
S1=2;    
End[]    
EndPackage[]
```

In first code, using `?` can get `` Functions`S1=1 `` and `` Funstions`Test1`K1=2 `` properly.

But in second code, only  `` Functions`S1=1 `` could be found, where is `` Funstions`Test1`K1=2 `` or `` Test1`K1=2 ``?

In third code, why the result is `` Functions`S1=2 `` not `` Functions`S1=1 ``? And where is `` Funstions`Test1`S1 ``?

How can I understand these differences.

Sry I'm newbie and not good at English, the question may not be described appropriately.

Comment: Closely related: [How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/5478)

Comment: For the second one ``?Test1`*`` is there and in the 3rd example ``Functions`S1`` is still available to lookup after `Begin`.