# The introduction for Context in Wagner's book is out of date?

Tags: evaluation, packages, symbols, contexts

In Section 8.1.1 (P230 of the book, P249 of the PDF) of [Wagner's book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/1871), the following example is shown:

```
x = 5;
temp`x = 6;
Begin["temp`"];
{x, Global`x}
```

The output is claimed to be:

> ```
> {6, 5}
> ```

But actually in version 8 and 9, the real behavior is:

[image]

Have I missed something, or this example is just outdated?

If so, do there exist other outdated parts in this book? Should we start a collection or something?