# Is there a free version of the Springer book "Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica"?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, simulation, reference-request

Is there a free version of the Springer book:

$$\text{Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica}$$

by Rose and Smith ... available on the internet?

Comment: Currently mathStatica is supported on V12, but not V13, at least not yet as of this comment.

Answer (score 22):

The printed version of the 2002 edition was printed 3 times and sold out 3 times;  Springer and Google recently started selling it (book only) as a PDF eBook (no software) on the Springer and Google sites for $79.

I know other authors (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat/)) have gone to some trouble to make their books available here on stack exchange ... We are delighted to be able to make the same PDF eBook version (2002 edition) available for FREE to stackexchange users at:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

This is a complete PDF version of the original 2002 printed edition. Although no software is included (neither *Mathematica* nor *mathStatica*), the methods, theorems, summary tables, examples, exercises, theorems etc are all useful and relevant ... even as a reference text for people who do not even have *Mathematica*.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathstatica.com](http://www.mathstatica.com/images/RoseSmith2002FirstEditionFree.jpg))</sub>

One can either download:

- the entire book as a single download file ... with live clickable Table of Contents etc,  ... or
- chapter by chapter.

**iBooks installation**

To install as an iBook:

- Download the entire book as a single PDF file
- Then drag it into iBooks (under the section: PDF files).

**iPad installation**

To install on an iPad:

- First install it as an iBook (as above)
- Open iTunes; select your iPad; click on Books: select the book and sync it over to your iPad.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder, since there is a 2002 edition, and M has added so many new statistics/probability functions since then, if the code in that 2002 will still run without too much trouble and compatibility issues. I am downloading it now ....

Comment: @Nasser Actually, surprisingly little has changed in the book content between the 2002 edition and the current 2013 edition. This is because the BOOK was written in terms of using statistical operators … operators like an:  Expect function, a Variance function and a Prob function … So, the approach to solving problems does not change - just more choice as to which function to use. What _has_ changed considerably since 2002 is (i) the mathStatica software itself (about 3 times larger), and (ii) the live notebook content, which is far more exciting/interactive now thanks to `Manipulate` etc.