# How to get `Series` to recognize user-defined function has pole

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

**Edit for clarity:**  How does *Mathematica*'s function `Series` know that `Gamma[x]` has a pole at `x=0`?  When `Series` is called to expand near `x=0`, it gives the proper `1/x` term in its Laurent expansion.  I need to copy this behavior of `Series` to user-defined functions.

```
Series[Gamma[x],{x,0,1}]
```

> 1/x-EulerGamma+1/12 (6 EulerGamma^2+[Pi]^2) x+O[x]^2

---

In the package I'm writing I have several complicated functions that have simple poles near isolated points. These functions are to be evaluated only when its arguments are numerical.  Otherwise, for the sake of brevity of the output, these functions remain unevaluated and is supposed to act like a special function.

Simple example:  $$f(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$$

**Task:**  I would like to be able to carry out a `Series` expansion in $x$; especially around $x=0$ where it should yield the $1/x$ pole term in the Laurent series:

Here is what I did:

```
SetAttributes[f,NumericFunction];
f[x_?NumericQ] := 1/x Cos[x];
Derivative[n_][f][x_] := Derivative[n][1/# Cos[#] &][x];
```

So now, I test this, and try to obtain the expansion near $x=\pi/2$.

```
Series[f[x], {x, Pi/2, 2}]
```

[image]

which works, but around $x=0$,

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

I get an error.  **So,** how can I tell `Series` that at $x=0$, the function `f` starts at $1/x$?  I need `Series` to behave just as it would if I gave it the full functional form explicitly:

```
Series[1/x Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, am error.

Comment: The example of `1/x Cos[x]` is just a simple example.  In the application I'm developing, the expression is *substantially* more complicated.  I would rather let `f[x]` be an abbreviation for this complicated analytic expression, and let users be able work with `f` instead of the complicated expression.

Comment: Have you tried using `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to use it in this case.  Would you demonstrate?

Comment: Is there a reason you define a derivative for `f` ?

Comment: Yes, because without it, `Series` wouldn't work on `f` anymore -- even at regular points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to David B. Wagner's book, [Power Programming with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat) (ch 9.3), you can define upvalues for `Series`.  Here's how I implement it:

```
Clear[f]; ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, NumericFunction]
f[x_?NumericQ] = Cos[x]/x;

(*So that Series works at regular points*)
Derivative[n_][f][x_] := Derivative[n][1/# Cos[#] &][x];

(*Give explicit definition at singular point*)
f /: Series[f[x_], {x_, 0, n_}] := If[n >= -1, 
   1/x + Series[Cos[x]/x - 1/x, {x, 0, n}], SeriesData[x, 0, List[], -1, -1, 1]];
```

First, the built-in behavior of `Series` on an expression is that if the desired order `n` is lower than the order of the lowest non-vanishing term `a` of that expression, the output is `O[x]^a`.

Finally, explicitly give the singular terms in the Series expansion, followed by an explicit instruction to compute the series with the singular parts subtracted.

Unfortunately, this is not robust against expressions containing `f[x]`:

```
Series[x*f[x], {x,0,3}]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered.
>   
>  Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>   
>  Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind mucking with internal symbols, you can add the following:

```
f /: System`Private`InternalSeries[f[x_], e_] := Series[Cos[x]/x, e]
f[x_?NumericQ] := Cos[x]/x
```

Then:

```
Series[x f[x], {x, 0, 3}] //TeXForm
```

> $1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$

and:

```
Series[f[x]/x, {x, 0, 3}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{24}+O\left(x^4\right)$

behave the way you want, and `f` also evaluates as desired:

```
f[x]
f[1]
```

> f[x]
>
> Cos[1]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect; because now it works like a built-in function. +1

Answer (score 2):

Given the numerical nature of the definitions, this problem can best be attacked using the `NumericalCalculus` package:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

Chop[Normal[NSeries[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]]]

(* ==> 1.00002/x - 0.5 x *)
```

To improve the numerical accuracy of the results, you may want to adjust the `WorkingPrecision` and `Radius` options depending on the actual function you're trying to expand. See the documentation for [`NSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/NSeries.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm writing a package that is largely meant for analytic manipulations.  I must make the task work for `Series` and not `NSeries`.  How does *Mathematica* know that $\Gamma(x)$ has a pole at $x=0$, so that `Series` starts at `1/x`?  I need to mimic this effect.

Comment: I have edited my question, and hopefully, it is clearer.

Comment: You reference to `Gamma` is confusing because it doesn't actually do what you seem to be asking for in the question. E.g., `Gamma[1/3]` doesn't evaluate even though the argument is numeric. Obviously your question wants that to evaluate, too. So I don't know what the real goal is.

Comment: Ok, the line `f[x_?NumericQ]=...` has made the question confusing.  I have completely reworded the question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/changing-default-behavior-of-series-to-give-slightly-different-seriesdata