# Changing default behavior of Series to give slightly different SeriesData

Tags: function-construction, series-expansion

I am working with complicated expressions `expr` that contains the *symbolic* function `f[x]` which I know to have a pole at `x=0`.  I would like to carry out `Series` expansions of `expr` and therefore `f[x]` near `x=0` in *Mathematica*.  The default behavior of `Series` is to yield a `SeriesData` that starts at zero powers of `x`:

```
Series[f[x],{x,0,1}] // FullForm

(* SeriesData[x, 0, List[f[0], Derivative[1][f][0]], 0, 2, 1] *)
```

[image]

This output is correct as long as `f[x]` is regular at `x=0`.  But the `f[x]` I'm using has a pole at `x=0`.  How do I tell `Series` to start the expansion of `f[x]` at order `x^-1`?

I basically need the behavior:

```
Series[f[x],{x,0,1}] // FullForm

(* SeriesData[x, 0, List[fRef[0], Derivative[1][fReg][0]], Derivative[2][fReg][0]], -1, 2, 1] *)
```

[image]

1. I **especially** need to avoid globally defining down-values of `f[x]` as in `f[x]:=g[x]/x` since I would like to keep `f[x]` intact throughout the rest of the evaluations in the notebook.  However, if such a definition can be made to be confined *within* the `Series` function, that would be perfectly fine.
2. I also would not like to define a whole new `SeriesNew` function: I'm writing a package and I prefer the user to be able to functions already familiar to him.

---

**My attempt**:

I tried to define an up-value for `f[x]`:

```
Series[f[x_], y__] ^:= Series[1/x, y] Series[fReg[x], y];
(* SeriesData[x, 0, List[f2[0], Derivative[1][f2][0]], -1, 1, 1] *)
```

[image]

Which is OK (except that the order $\mathcal{O}(x^1)$ term is hidden).  But then `Series` reverts back to its default assumption about `f[x]` when I have a more complicated expresssion involving `f[x]`:

```
Series[x f[x] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}]

(* SeriesData[x, 0, List[1, f[0], Plus[Rational[-1, 2], Derivative[1][f][0]]], 0, 3, 1] *)
```

**Dream:** it would be perfect if I could edit the built-in `Series[expr_, ...]` function so that I can add at the very top, the following line:

```
expr /. f[x]- >1/x g[x]
```

and that it can see the pole at `x=0`, and treat the symbolic `g[x]` as a regular function.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I feel like `Series` is a function that is designed and intended to give the power series (not Laurent series) expansion of a function.

It does its best, so if you did something like `Series[Cos[x]/x,{x,0,10}]` you **will** get the Laurent series though. However, if you are using unspecified `f[x]`, it will assume `f[x]` has a power series expansion and give it (as you have seen).

If your function `f[x]` is really not specified, you may still want this expansion but you want it to include the appropriate $x^{-1}$ term in the series. You can $f(x)=g(x)/x$ and just do `Series[g[x]/x,{x,0,10}]`. You would then need to clean up that expression to be in terms of $f$ instead of $g$, which you can do as:

```
DRule[n_] :=
 If[n == 0, g[0] -> Residue[f[x], x, 0],
  Solve[
    ReplaceAll[D[x f[x] == g[x], {x, n}], x -> 0],
    ReplaceAll[D[g[x], {x, n}], x -> 0]
    ][[1, 1]]
  ]
s[x_]=Series[g[x]/x, {x, 0, 10}]
ReplaceAll[s[x], Table[DRule[n], {n, 0, 10}]]
```

You probably will find an easy pattern to eliminate the need for a DRule function that is quite so complicated, i.e. $g^{(n)}(0)=nf^{(n-1)}(0)$.

I'm not sure if this is what you want because it's not clear to me what you want to do with this expression once you have it. Please add a comment if there's something more that might help.

Comment: I wrote answer answer to my own question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60891/how-to-get-series-to-recognize-user-defined-function-has-pole/63055#63055.  It looks like it is possible to define upvalues for Series.  But as I mentioned there, it doesn't work for compound expressions.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: `Series` seems to be smart enough to recognize that certain special functions have a pole.  For example, `Series[Gamma[x]],{x,0,1}` and `Series[BesselY[1,x]],{x,0,1}` all give a leading `1/x`.  So either `Series` or the special function have some information that has been set...

Comment: I also give an example where `Series` recognizes a pole. However, it will not do so with expressions containing unspecified functions like `f[x]` -- it will assume $f(x)$ is regular at the center of your series. You've asked for a work-around. I've provided one. If this one doesn't work for you, you'll have to explain why it doesn't work so I (or someone else) can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you give [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for the private symbol `` System`Private`InternalSeries `` instead, you should get the behavior you want:

```
f /: System`Private`InternalSeries[f[x_], {y_, y0_, n_}] := System`Private`InternalSeries[
    g[x]/x,
    {y, y0, n}
]
```

Then:

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{g(0)}{x}+g'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x g''(0)+O\left(x^2\right)$

and something more complicated:

```
Series[x f[x^2] + f[Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{g(0)}{x}+g(1)+x g'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(g(1)-g'(1)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$