# matrix multiplication speed

Tags: matrix

Consider the codes below:

```
dim = 500;

rd = RandomReal[1, {dim, dim}];

W = Table[{rd[[i]]}\[Transpose].{rd[[i]]}, {i, 1, dim}];

A = RandomReal[1, {dim, dim}];

x = Table[A.W[[i]], {i, 1, dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming

y = Table[A.{rd[[i]]}\[Transpose].{rd[[i]]}, {i, 1, dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`W[[i]]`is equal to `{rd[[i]]}\[Transpose].{rd[[i]]}`so basically the x multiplication is the same as y one. However y is around 3 times faster than x. Does anybody know why y is faster? I though because I had stored matrix `W[[i]]` then multiplication x would be faster, specially that y needs to compute `W[[i]]`first but x has it already.

It seems if we have a matrix in this form `W = a.b` in which `a` is a column matrix and `b` is a row matrix then `W.a.b` is faster than `W.W`:

```
In[1]:= dim = 2000;

In[2]:= a = RandomReal[1, {dim, 1}];

In[3]:= b = RandomReal[1, {1, dim}];

In[4]:= W = a.b;

In[5]:= W.(a.b);(*n^2+n^3 operations*)// AbsoluteTiming

Out[5]= {0.229023, Null}

In[6]:= W.W;(*n^3 operations*)// AbsoluteTiming

Out[6]= {0.183018, Null}

In[7]:= (W.a).b;(*2 n^2 operations*)// AbsoluteTiming

Out[7]= {0.021002, Null}
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to decompose every arbitrary matrix like this: `W =a.b`?

---

**Edit**

I added the number of multiplication operations for each calculation after reading the answer of `bill s`. Now, its clear why the last one is the fastest. So, the order by which we do the multiplication matters, at least sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to see what is happening:

```
z1 = Table[A.({rd[[i]]}\[Transpose].{rd[[i]]}), {i, 1,  dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
z2 = Table[(A.{rd[[i]]}\[Transpose]).{rd[[i]]}, {i, 1, dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

which explicitly groups the calculations using parenthesis. As you found, `z1` is slower than `z2`, which makes sense because `z1` is essentially the product of two matrices, while `z2` is the product of a matrix and a vector, followed by the product of a vector and vector.

For example, say you are multiplying as in `z1`. This takes `n^3` multiplications where the matrices are size `n` (500 in the above example). On the other hand, `A.rd` takes `n^2` multiplications and results in a vector. Then the outer product of the two vectors requires another `n^2` multiplications, so `z2` takes a total of `2 n^2` multiplications.

It is certainly not possible to reduce every matrix to a product of two vectors. One way to see this is that the rank of a product of two vectors is at most 1, so any `W` with rank greater than 1 cannot be decomposed this way.

Comment: I didn't get. Isn't the number of arithmetic calculations the same? I guess there are more efficient algorithms for the product of a matrix and a vector than that of a matrix and a matrix.

Comment: @yashar, Matrix-matrix and matrix-vertor multiplications have a sufficiently different number of operations.

Comment: @yashar Have a look at an example in David Wagner's book named "Matrix chain multiplication". He uses dynamic programming to optimize the multiplication strategy, and discusses this issue at length.

Comment: @ybeltukov `z1` is a matrix matrix product and z2 is a matrix vector and then a vector vector product. The number of arithmetic calculations must be the same.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin the only book I found was this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat

Comment: @yashar That's the one. Search for a chapter on dynamic programming.

Comment: I think the second part needs n^2 multiplications too so in general there are 2*n^2 multiplication for z2. After the multiplication of `W` and `a` we have a column matrix, its multiplication with `b`, a row matrix, is another matrix.