# Good sources of programming exercises for learning Mathematica programming?

Tags: reference-request

I'm learning *Mathematica* programming. I wonder if there are any good sources of programming exercises particularly suitable for practicing *Mathematica* programming.

Comment: Follow [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/3066) to find out how get David Wagner's book as a free download.

Comment: Most questions on this site are good exercises. Try to solve the questions on your own, then check the existing solutions. Look for new questions to answer and try to answer them before anyone else does.

Comment: Also look at https://projecteuler.net/ -- the higher numbered (more recent) problems are mostly very difficult, but many of the lower numbered ones are approachable.

Comment: Pickett's suggestion is probably one of the best ways to learn. You can always surf the documentation, too, and try to make sure you understand how the examples work (although it's a slightly more passive method).