# Wolfram MAtematica

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, wolfram-cloud

I want to learn Wolfram Language can anyone suggest some books from where I can start?
p.s. I am basic at Wolfram Language ,and now I want to high knowledge.

Comment: I recommend you to learn new topics WITH Mathematica. Just query Google with something like "Bayesian Statistics Using Mathematica". You will find a lot of books, papers, talks, etc. Also see the Mathematica Journal (www.mathematica-journal.com/).

Comment: Hi,Thanks Piotr I will start doing it now :)

Comment: Strongly recommend studying *Power Programming with Mathematica* by David B. Wagner. You can find out how to download it free by reading [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066)

Comment: I did it,thanks lot m_goldberg