# Formatting Tables in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting

Ok, I created a table

```
Table[j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}] // TableForm
```

and the result is fine, from 1-4 in each column. Now, what if I wanted to extend this table into something that looks like this:

```
Table[{something, Table[{i, j}, {j, 1, 8, 1}]}, {i, 1, 4, 1}] // TableForm
```

only without that `something` written in the front of every row. I wrote it because I don't know Mathematica enough to do it any other way. But this second Table is what I want, I want it to look like that, without that "something". It is not a big problem, if I can't get rid of that but I would be happy to...

The other thing is, I want to export it to a .txt or .dat file that would not have all those {{soidn,soig},{ig,irg}} brackets inside.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should really take more care in formatting (and formulating) your questions. You can find some tips on using markdown to format your posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You really need to develop your basic _Mathematica_ skills. I strongly recommend you study *Power Programming with Mathematica* by David B. Wagner. You can find out how to download it free by reading [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
Table[{"    ", Table[{i, j}, {j, 1, 8, 1}]}, {i, 1, 4, 1}]
```

which has no "something", and you might also put it in the `TableForm`if needed. Alternatively you might make a `Grid`out of it:

```
 Grid[Table[{"    ", Table[{i, j}, {j, 1, 8, 1}]}, {i, 1, 4, 1}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

As to your second question, what about

```
    Table[{"", 
  Table[ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 8, 1}]}, {i, 1, 4, 
  1}]

(*   {{"", {"1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,4", "1,5", "1,6", "1,7", 
   "1,8"}}, {"", {"2,1", "2,2", "2,3", "2,4", "2,5", "2,6", "2,7", 
   "2,8"}}, {"", {"3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "3,4", "3,5", "3,6", "3,7", 
   "3,8"}}, {"", {"4,1", "4,2", "4,3", "4,4", "4,5", "4,6", "4,7", 
   "4,8"}}}   *)
```

??

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something as simple as

```
Join[{something}, #] & /@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 8}]
```

> ```
> {{something, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}}, 
>  {something, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}}, 
>  {something, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}}, 
>  {something, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
TableForm[Table[{i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 8}], TableDirections -> {Column, Column, Row}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 8}], 1] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Exporting:

```
Export["filename.csv", Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 4}, {j, 8}], 1]]
```