# Why does the Derivative function not appear in the tree form?

Tags: trees, head

I was learning that set delay doesn't evaluate things until its calling time. Hence, I thought that something like the followng:

`dfdt := D[f[t],t]`

would not evaluate the derivative until dfdt was called. Let me show you what I tried:

[image]

as you can tell, the Head is not the derivative, as I would ave thought. Why is this? Is there a misconception that I have about how mathematica works?

---

It still doesn't work (display the `Derivative` in the tree even if I say "unevaluate"):

[image]

Comment: You are right that := delays evaluation, but when you submit the expression subsequently (as in In[65]), Mathematica "evaluates" it. Try this: `ClearAll[f, d, x]; d := D[f, x];` then evaluate `d`. Now define `f = Sin[x]` then evaluate `d` again. Because of the delayed definition you can redefine `f` as many times as you would like and `d` will always resolve it.

Comment: You might also want to look at `Hold`, etc. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html).

Comment: Evaluation in _Mathematica_ is complex. I strongly recommend you study Chapter 7 of *Power Programming with Mathematica* by David B. Wagner, which has a highly accessible discussion of evaluation. You can find out how to download it **free** by reading [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066)

Comment: @mfvonh so that means that the derivative is not actually done until I "call" the variable, right?

Comment: Yes. The definition `dfdt` keeps `f` as is in the RHS, then computes the derivative (and in doing so, resolves `f` at that exact moment) each time you "call" it (clearer to say "evaluate" in Mathematica)

Comment: @m_goldberg you choose to hold this question. Please show me were I can easily find it in the documentation please. I'd find it super helpful, since I've been reading books and documentation like crazy for the past 3 days. Thanks in advance :)

Btw, I also tried putting `Unevaluated[dfd2]` and it didn't quite work either. Not sure, if I still have a misconception. Is it just impossible to display `D` in the tree form of an expression?

Comment: I see. But even if I try to `TreeForm[Unevaluated[d]]` in your example, it doesn't show the derivative in the tree diagram :/

Comment: Perhaps the behavior may not be intuitive, but reading the documentation for `Unevaluated` pays off. To quote, *Unevaluated works only where it appears; it is not propagated:*. On the other hand, `Hold` helps. Compare `TreeForm[D[f,x]]` and `TreeForm[Hold[D[f,x]]]`. Also, note the mention of `Unevaluated` suppressing evaluation when it's an argument to a function. Try also `TreeForm[somehead[Unevaluated[D[f,x]]]]`

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Please try `TreeForm@Inactivate[D[f[a, {t1, t2, t3}, {c1, c2, c3}], c1], D] /. 
 Inactive[D] -> "D"`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have defined

```
f[a_, cs_List, ts_List] := cs.Exp[-(ts - a)^2]
```

setting

```
dfd2 := D[f[a, {c1, c2, c3}, {t1, t2, t3}], t1]
```

defines `dfd2` without taking into consideration the *current* value of `f`. You can inspect the definition of `dfd2` by evaluating `?dfd2`, which returns exactly what you typed above. Then, whenever `dfd2` is evaluated, it looks for any definition associated with the symbol `f` at that moment in order to manipulate the expression. This means that `dfd2` returns

```
2 c1 Exp[-(a - t1)^2] (a - t1)
```

You can compare this behavior with that of

```
immediate = D[f[a, {c1, c2, c3}, {t1, t2, t3}], t1]
```

Check the expression returned by `?immediate`. You'll see that, while in the definition of `dfd2` the expression `f[___]` is kept in an unevaluated form, in `immediate` the right hand side is simplified at definition time.

Among other things, this means that if you redefine `f`, as with `Clear[f]; f[___] := 0`, `dfd2` will evaluate to `0`, reflecting the change in `f`, while `immediate` will remain unmodified. This, again, is because `f` does not appear in the definition of `immediate`, which you can check through `?immediate`.