# What is the definition of head in Mathematica?

Tags: head

I know (by practice) what a *head* is, but I am unable to find the appropriate words to actually define it. I would like to see a precise definition of *head* using the appropriate technical words involved. Hopefully, this should provide me with a better understanding of how *Mathematica* works.

Comment: Note that as stated in the documentation, "Heads need not be symbols", e.g., `FixedPointList[Head, f[x][y][z]] // Most` returns `{f[x][y][z], f[x][y], f[x], f, Symbol}`

Comment: An answer may be found in the first tutoria,l [Everything Is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), linked in the documentation for [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagner's *[Power Programming with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/731)* begins chapter 2.1.1 thus:

[image]

The definition of *head* is its position in the expression. If you want to really understand expressions I encourage you to follow the link above to the answer here on *Mathematica*.SE where the book is available for free, and continue reading starting at the point I quoted.