# Function input syntax

Tags: functions, syntax, syntax-highlighting

My functions are

```
W[L_, r_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 r*L - 6 L (r*L) + 6 (r*L)^2;
T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_, W_] := ((u/d^2)* W[L, r]+6 u (L - 1)) + koff (u/d^2) W[L, r]
```

How to write correctly `T` function: is `W` an input or not? What is the difference between `T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_, W_]` and `T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_]`?

How doest Mathematica understand `W` and `T` in both cases?

It seems that sometimes there is no difference but if I create the third function `K=f(T,W)` it will affect. And Mathematica gives different colors of `W[L,r]` in different cases.

Comment: Have you already worked your way through the following tutorials? [Defining functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html); [Functions and Programs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html); [How To - Work with Variables and Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithVariablesAndFunctions.html)

Comment: You don't need the `W` in the definition of `T`. Just write `T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_] := ...`

Comment: @eldo I understood that, I am just wondering why and how _Mathematica_ interpret if I include `W` in the definition of `T`.

Comment: @MarcoB didn't find the answer in these tutorials.

Comment: @MarcoB Why the question has been put on hold? It does not arise from syntax mistake, it's not possible find in documentation.I was trying to understand how _Mathematica_ works and why it interprets my syntax incorrectly. (I understand rules but I didn't understand what happens internally in it when I didn't follow the rule) Sorry, if my question is confusing.

Comment: Maria, I voted to close this question because it stems from a misunderstanding of the semantics of the language which would be difficult to address appropriately on this site. Remember: a close vote is not a judgement of the quality of the question or the asker! It simply evaluates the appropriateness of the question and the likelihood that an answer will help others as well. As it happens, your question received excellent answers by Edmund and m_goldberg that will hopefully help. I sincerely hope that you will stick around and participate in this site as you get acquainted with *Mathematica*!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused due to the naming convention you are using.  For `T` you can use any symbol to represent the function `W` in `T`.  It is perhaps best not to use the symbol `W` in `T`'s definition because it is confusing you.  Try using `f` instead.

```
ClearAll[T, W];
W[L_, r_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 r*L - 6 L (r*L) + 6 (r*L)^2
T[L_, r_, d_, koff_, u_, f_] := ((u/d^2)*f[L, r] + 6 u (L - 1)) + koff (u/d^2) f[L, r]
```

There I have used `f` the symbol that takes the function.  Now, when I call the function with `W` all works as expected and it is clear what `W` is and what `f` is.

```
T[L, r, d, koff, u, W]
(* 6*(-1 + L)*u + ((1 + 3*L + 2*L^2 - 6*L*r - 6*L^2*r + 6*L^2*r^2)*u)/d^2 + 
 (koff*(1 + 3*L + 2*L^2 - 6*L*r - 6*L^2*r + 6*L^2*r^2)*u)/d^2 *)
```

$$\frac{\text{koff} u \left(6 L^2 r^2-6 L^2 r+2 L^2-6 L r+3 L+1\right)}{d^2}+\frac{u \left(6 L^2 r^2-6 L^2 r+2 L^2-6 L r+3 L+1\right)}{d^2}+6 (L-1) u$$

Also, a point to note is that you should not create symbols that start with capital letters in your notebooks. These may clash with current **or future** symbols that Wolfram adds to the language. For example, consider `N` or `E`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this simple case.

```
w[x_, y_] := 1 + x y
t[x_, y_, z_] := w[x, y]/z
```

Then

```
t[2, 3, 5]
```

gives

> `7/5`

which shows *Mathematica* recognized and evaluated the reference to `w[x, y]` in the definition of `t`, substituted the correct values of `x` and `y`, and got the correct result for `t[2, 3, 5]`. It will do the same for your definitions.

Comment: I do understand that it works.My question is not about that. How does _Mathematica_ recognize `W`? For me it was interesting,because I did obtain correct results with `W`-input, and only once occasionally got list of lists as a result of `T`-output. I am interested **why**?

Comment: @Maria. Sorry that I misunderstood your question. Not sure I understand the question in your comment either. However, if you are seeking to learn how _Mathematica_ evaluates a general expression, I recommend  reading Chapter 7 of David Wagner's classic book. You can download a free copy by going to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066). Wagner's discussion of how _Mathematica_ works internally is the best I know.

Comment: Why then a question has been put on hold? It does not arise from syntax mistake, it's not possible find in documentation.I was trying to understand how _Mathematica_ works and why it interprets my syntax incorrectly. (I understand rules but I didn't understand what happens internally in it when I didn't follow the rule) Sorry, if my question is confusing and thanks for the book.

Comment: @Maria. I voted to close because I misunderstood what you were asking until you clarified your intent in a comment. Others might have done the same. I will not vote to reopen it as it stands because it still reads as a simple misunderstanding of function evaluation as covered in the documentation. Should you edit it, it will automatically come up for reopen consideration, but unless you clarify it so reads as a non-trivial question about evaluation, it is not likely to get enough votes to be reopened.