# How to input functions into Mathematica

Tags: regions, homework

[image: I can't figure this out SOS]

I need help with this assignment like asap. I've never been taught how to use this program and our math department expects us to learn how to use it, but it is just so complicated!!! Please help me out!

Comment: I literally tried to put the functions in and then do the first assignment and plot the region, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: you should show the code you tried in the question, otherwise it looks like you put no effort into it except scanning the page, and nobody can tell where you are stuck.

Comment: If you need to teach yourself _Mathematica_, I strongly recommend David Wagner's classic book. You can download a ***free*** copy by going to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066).

Answer (score 3):

**2 (a)**

```
f[x_] := x + 2;
g[x_] := Sin[x];
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, 
     {x, 0, π/2},
     Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, π/2}]
```

$-1+\pi +\frac{\pi ^2}{8}$

**2 (b)**

Follow the above procedure.

**3 (a)**

```
p[x_] := x^2;
r[x_] := 8 - x^2;
 Plot[{p[x], r[x]}, {x, 0, π/2},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

```
a = RevolutionPlot3D[r[x], {x, 0, π/2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 10}}];
b = RevolutionPlot3D[p[x], {x, 0, π/2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, 10}}];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help with the other portions of this problem?

Comment: @CakeTV:  As a former professor, I'm reluctant to fill in all details lest I solve your homework problem for you; you wouldn't learn all you should and it would be unfair to other students.

Comment: But the problem is I seriously have no way to figure out how to use this program. We are not taught it, we are just expected to figure it out. If you can just help me by telling me the commands and such, and if I should do the same thing for the next one, then please help

Comment: @CakeTV:  This is not the site for students to *learn* *Mathematica* or have others answer their homework problems for them.  Go to your teacher and explain that you've never learned *Mathematica*.

Comment: Well, perhaps a good will student may _learn Mathematica_ here ...