# Free symbols in an expression

Tags: core-language, symbols

I am starting to learn the basic MMA grammar these days. I hope I do not ask too much stupid questions. Here is one of them:

Getting free symbols in an expression can be done by following codes:

```
x = a + b;
y = x*x + x*c + d;
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]

> {a, b, c, d}
```

These is no problem yet. The problem comes when the expression comes with `Hold`, `HoldForm` or `Defer`.

```
y = Defer[x*x] + x*c + d;
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]

> {a, b, c, d, a + b}

y // TreeForm
```

[image: tree1]

The part I do not understand is `Cases` return `a+b` as free symbol, but `TreeForm` has a leaf of `x`. How to interpolate these outpus. To make the question even intersting, consider:

```
y = Defer[x*x] + HoldForm[x*c] + d;
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]

> {d, a + b, c}

y // TreeForm
```

[image: tree2]

If I want the free symbol as shown in `TreeForm`, which is `c, d, x` in the last example. What should I input?

Comment: Have you seen [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html).  Try `Variables@y` instead.

Comment: @Edmund Thanks, `Variables` is promising, but it cannot totally solve this problem, it only works for `polynomial`. Therefore, for general expression it won't work. E.g. ` Defer[x*x] + HoldForm[Sin[x]*c] + d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has little to do with `Hold` or any of its cousins. It has to do with the evaluator recursively evaluating symbols until it gets no changes. This can be demonstrated by using `Trace`.

```
x = a + b;
y = Hold[x*x] + x*c + d;
Trace[DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]]
```

[image: trace1]

Note that `Cases` returned `{a, b, c, d, x, x}`, but then `x` got evaluated in the argument sequence passed to `DeleteDuplicates`, producing the result you don't want.

To get what you want you could do the following, using `Block` to locally make `x` a free variable.

```
x = a + b;
y = Hold[x*x] + Hold[x]*c + d;
Block[{x},
  Trace[DeleteDuplicates@ Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]]]
```

[image: trace2]

But consider that if you assign `y` within the block, you don't need to worry about `Hold`.

```
x = a + b;
Block[{x},
 y = x*x + x*c + d;
 Trace[DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]]]
```

[image: trace3]

#### Update 1

As to why

```
 y = Hold[x*x] + Hold[x]*c + d;
 Cases[y, _Symbol, {-1}]
```

produces

> `{d, c, a + b, a + b, a + b}`

rather than

> `{d, c, x, x, x}`

This has a simple explanation. `Cases` actually returns `{d, c, x, x, x}`, but recall this is the short form for `List[d, c, x, x, x]`. Now `List` is function (although you may be thinking of it as a data type), so the evaluator evaluates this function call as well any other. The 2nd step in the evaluation cycle is to evaluate the function's argument, so of course `x` gets evaluated.

#### Update 2

After thinking this over for a while, it occurred to me that you might be interested in another approach to restricting evaluation. This will give a display form that meets your requirements.

```
y = ReleaseHold[Hold[x*x + x*c + d] /. HoldPattern[s : x | c | d] -> HoldForm[s]]
```

> `d + c x + x^2`

`y` can still be evaluated with

```
y // ReleaseHold
```

> `(a + b)^2 + (a + b) c + d`

but now

```
result = DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[y, HoldForm[_], {-2}]
```

gives

> `{d, c, x}`

However, remember this is for display only. The internal form is

```
result // FullForm
```

> `List[HoldForm[d], HoldForm[c], HoldForm[x]]`

Like `y`, `result` can be evaluated with `ReleaseHold`.

Comment: Is this mean there is nothing we can do to prevent the result from `Case` evaluated, unless put `x` into a local scope? `Trace@Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]` will also evaluate the result.

Comment: I find evaluation of expression is not easy to understand. Could you please provide me some links on this topic? The documentation is a little confusing.

Comment: @Kattern. If a variable bound to value, i.e., has an own-value in a given scope, the easy way to make the evaluator ignore that binding is to put the variable into a scope where it isn't bound.

Comment: @Kattern. Recommend David Wagner's book. See chapter 7. Free download from [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/3066)

Comment: The local scope part I can understand. I just do not know whether we can defer the evaluation for result of `Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]`. Because the result is also evaluated for `Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]`.

Comment: I will definitely check that book. Thanks a lot for your recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

```
x = a + b;

y = Defer[x*x + g] + 6 x*c + Pi*d + Sin[a*E];

Variables@Level[y, {-1}]

(*  {a, b, c, d, g}  *)

Variables@Cases[y, _Symbol, -1]

(*  {a, b, c, d, g}  *)
```

EDIT:

```
y = Defer[x*x] + HoldForm[x*c] + d;

var = Cases[y, 
   z_Symbol?(! NumericQ[#] &) :> If[AtomQ[z], z, HoldForm[z]], -1] // 
  Union
```

[image]

```
var // RotateLeft // TreeForm
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the point here.

Comment: In a comment, [Edmund](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund) suggested using `Variable`. You replied in a comment that it only worked with polynomials. This shows that that you can readily get a list of the variables with `Variable`. I show two different ways.

Comment: Using `Variable` in both ways does not return the results needed, but also thanks for the answer provided.

Comment: Recommend that you clarify what you mean by "Free symbols".

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, but I do not have a suitable name for what I want. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Do you have any suggestion on how to name what I want in the question?