# Defining vector components - $RecursionLimit

Tags: vector

I am trying to define a vector, $\vec{u}$, with components $u_x$ and $u_y$.

However, when I type `u = {Subscript[u, x], Subscript[u, y]}`, I get the following error:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {Subscript[u, x]}.
```

Using the `Indexed[]` function produces the same error.

Just curious why this happens, and how to correct the problem in this scenario?

Comment: As a general note: Better not use `Subscript` at all; it leads to many nasty things. Why does this happen? The same happens with every call of the form `u = f[u]`. At the moment you make the assignment, it forces Mathematica to reinsert the definition on the right hand side which produces `f[f[u]]`,`f[f[f[u]]]`, `f[f[f[f[u]]]]` and so on.

Comment: You could consider one of the options presented in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158451/45431)