# Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of a complex substitution

Tags: warning-messages, system

I am trying to do the following :

[image]

How do I obtain an expression for $\epsilon$

Comment: Why don't you trivially cut-and-paste the definition of σ from the first equation into the second and be done?  Your syntax is all wrong too:  `Simplify[ ]`.  And there is no reason your Simplify call "knows" the first definition you've given.

Comment: Even after doing that I am not getting a simplified expression.

Comment: You could consider one of the options presented in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158451/45431)

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html)

```
Format[σ0] = Subscript["σ", 0];
Format[ϵ0] = Subscript["ϵ", 0];

σ = σ0/(1 - I ω τ);

ϵ = ϵ0 (1 + I σ/(ω ϵ0));

Simplify@ϵ
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply, subscripts don't work like that in *Mathematica*. When you define $\epsilon=\epsilon_\theta$, the $\epsilon$ on the right hand side is then substituted with the definition, because $\epsilon_\theta$ is not actually treated as its own variable.

```
σ = σθ (1 - I ω τ);
ϵ = ϵθ (1 + 
    I σ/(ω ϵθ));
Simplify[ϵ]
```

> ```
> ϵθ + σθ (τ + I/ω)
> ```

Please also note that `Simplify ϵ` is literally interpreted as `Simplify` times `ϵ`, and will not result in any simplification. The square brackets are necessary for `Simplify` to have any effect.

Please also note that as written in your screenshot, the imaginary unit `I` will not be evaluated, as it is part of a variable name. To multiply `I` by something, make sure there is a  (space) or `*` (asterisk) between them.

Comment: But I want the Sigma from equation 1 to be substituted into equation 2.

Comment: Then put a space between the imaginary unit and the sigma, otherwise it's one variable. Will edit that in momentarily.