# Mathematica Journal Article on Dependency Analysis

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone here have the volume 6 issue 1 of the Mathematica Journal. I am looking for its article by David B. Wagner on Power Programming: Dependency Analysis. I can find the package file but can't find the article which explain how it works. I looked on the website, all the Mathematica Journals are free but they have not uploaded this one yet stating: "CONTENTS OF BACK ISSUES OF THE MATHEMATICA JOURNAL ARE IN THE PROCESS OF BEING ADDED TO THIS ONLINE REPOSITORY."

If anyone has this article in print (which can be scanned) or pdf i really need it.

link: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/1943/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about Wolfram language but solicitation to distribute copyrighted material.

Comment: Are you aware that David Wagner speaks about Dependency Analysis in his book "Power Porgamming with Mathematica", chapter 7.3.7. ? The book is freely and legaly available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/5467)

Comment: I'm not sure about the copyright since, at least to my knowledge, the stuff on the Mathematica Journal is free. But I too think this question is out of scope here. Two things: As Adre mentions, we went through some pain to make David's book available for free and you can find it here on this site. Look at andre's link. Second, if in doubt I would write a friendly mail to wolfram asking for the material. I'm sure they give it to you for free.

Comment: I looked at the section 7.3.7 and it does cover the basics but for complete solution refers to the article in mathematica journal. I wrote an email to Wolfram email for mathematica journal yesterday but have not heard back from them yet.

Comment: I have been in contact with the editor, who is not a user in Mma.SE. The copyright of this is complicated, and there are no simple *yes/no* answers. My understanding is that free to access and free to distribute are different things. I suggest @user13892 should contact the editorial office directly, as they may be able to help in a case by case approach.

Comment: Thank you i contacted the editor and everything worked out for me :)