# Strange behaviour (or issue?) in using evaluation of held argument inside a table in Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, hold

I encountered a very strange behaviour on Mathematica using Evaluate on a held argument. Could anyone explain to me what is the subtlety (or is it a bug?)

Here is the expression:

```
 ClearAll[evaluateForThreeParameters, myParameter, setMyParameter];
 setMyParameter[p_] := (myParameter = p); 
 evaluateForThreeParameters[form_] := 
 Table[(setMyParameter[p]; Evaluate[form]),
       {p, {1, 2, 3}}];
 SetAttributes[evaluateForThreeParameters, HoldFirst];
 setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
 evaluateForThreeParameters[myParameter^2]
```

I would expect that the last expression should yield 
`{1, 4, 9}` but instead Mathematica (version 11.0.1.0 on MacOSX) evaluated this to: `{thisShouldNotAppear^2, 1, 4}`.

And what is even more strange, it is that if I embed the expression `Evaluate[form]` above inside the `Identity` function, which should change nothing, then I get the expected answer `{1,4,9}`, i.e. when I evaluate the expression

```
ClearAll[evaluateForThreeParameters, myParameter, setMyParameter];
setMyParameter[p_] := (myParameter = p); 
evaluateForThreeParameters[form_] := 
Table[(setMyParameter[p]; Identity[Evaluate[form]]),
      {p, {1, 2, 3}}];
SetAttributes[evaluateForThreeParameters, HoldFirst];
setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
evaluateForThreeParameters[myParameter^2]
```

Could anyone clarify what I am missing ?
Thanks, 
Pascal

Answer (score 3):

**Short Version**

The behaviour we see is by design.  It is due to the fact that we are using the special head `Evaluate` to force early evaluation of the second argument of `CompoundExpression` -- an argument which would otherwise be held until its time came to be evaluated.  If we wrap `Identity` around `Evaluate`, then this special action is prevented.

**Details: A Simpler Case**

We can see this behaviour using simpler expressions.  First, consider the ordinary use of `CompoundExpression`, whose shorthand operator form is `;`:

```
Print["one"]; Print["two"]

(* one
   two *)
```

No surprises here.  But if we wrap the second expression within `Evaluate`, it is evaluated *before* the compound expression itself is evaluated:

```
Print["one"]; Evaluate[Print["two"]]

(* two
   one *)
```

After that early evaluation and *two* is printed, the compound expression is effectively reduced to this:

```
Print["one"]; Null

(* one *)
```

`Evaluate` is a distinguished head that has special meaning built into the evaluator.  It causes its argument to be evaluated before the outer form itself, even though the outer form would otherwise hold the argument.  `CompoundExpression` is such a form because it has the `HoldAll` attribute:

```
Attributes[CompoundExpression]

(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

The evaluation process is detailed in [Power Programming with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/142) by David B. Wagner.  For the present case, see point 7(a) in section 7.1.3 on page 191.

`Evaluate` is only meaningful if it is directly contained within an expression which holds its argument.  Otherwise, it is essentially equivalent to `Identity`.  This is why the out-of-order evaluation is prevented if we wrap an explicit `Identity` around `Evaluate`:

```
Print["one"]; Identity[Evaluate[Print["two"]]]

(* one
   two *)
```

Note how `Evaluate` is no longer a top-level argument to `CompoundExpression`.

**Original Case From The Question**

We can now see what happens in the `Table` expression from the question:

```
setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
Table[(setMyParameter[p]; Evaluate[myParameter^2]), {p, {1, 2, 3}}]

(* {thisShouldNotAppear^2, 1, 4} *)
```

The presence of `Evaluate` is causing `myParameter^2` to be evaluated *before* `setMyParameter[p]`.  Thus, the results all appear to be "out by one" position.

A close inspection of the evaluation trace will show that the compound expression has already changed to `setMyParameter[p];thisShouldNotAppear^2` prior to its first evaluation, and is `setMyParameter[p];1` and `setMyParameter[p];4` in the subsequent evaluations:

```
setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
TracePrint[Table[(setMyParameter[p]; Evaluate[myParameter^2]), {p, {1, 2, 3}}]]

(* large output omitted *)
```

The introduction of `Identity` prevents this premature evaluation so we get the otherwise expected results:

```
setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
Table[(setMyParameter[p]; Identity[Evaluate[myParameter^2]]), {p, {1, 2, 3}}]

(* {1, 4, 9} *)
```

A simpler fix is to remove `Evaluate` altogether as it is not needed here:

```
ClearAll[evaluateForThreeParameters, myParameter, setMyParameter];
setMyParameter[p_] := (myParameter = p);
evaluateForThreeParameters[form_] := Table[(setMyParameter[p]; form), {p, {1, 2, 3}}];
SetAttributes[evaluateForThreeParameters, HoldFirst];
setMyParameter[thisShouldNotAppear];
evaluateForThreeParameters[myParameter^2]

(* {1, 4, 9} *)
```

Comment: Thank tou so much for this neat answer (and for advertising Wagner's book I didn't know). I did not understand that Evaluate was useless here which is the clean fix.