# How to plot region of integration in Mathematica?

Tags: regions, plotting

I want to set limits of integration in cylindrical polar coordinates for a function $f(r,\theta,z)$ over a region bounded below by the plane $z=0$, laterally by the circular cylinder $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and above by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2.$
I need complete procedure.
Because i am totally new to the mathematica.

Comment: Did you try plotting your surfaces to see if the region makes sense? `ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + (y - 1)^2 == 1, z == x^2 + y^2, z == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Maybe you accidentally reversed it?: Don't you want `0 <= z <= x^2+y^2` and not the opposite? -- Also look up and try out `RegionPlot3D` in addition to `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visualize the region of integration as follows if specified in rectangular / Cartesian coordinates. I am looking for a way to specify in cylindrical to the plot directly and will update when I find it.

```
With[{
    Δ=0.1
},
    RegionPlot3D[And[
        x^2+(y-1)^2<=1,
        z<=x^2+y^2,
        z>=0
    ],
        {x,-1-Δ,1+Δ},
        {y,0-Δ,2+Δ},
        {z,0-Δ,4+Δ},

        Mesh->10,
        MeshFunctions->{#3&},
        PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.5],Yellow],
        MeshShading->{Red,Automatic},

        PlotPoints->150,

        PlotTheme->"Detailed",
        AxesLabel->Automatic
    ]
]
```

---

```
ClearAll[getCartesian,getCylindrical];
getCartesian[field_]:=FullSimplify@TransformedField["Cylindrical"->"Cartesian",field,{r,θ,\[ScriptZ]}->{x,y,z}];
getCylindrical[field_]:=FullSimplify@TransformedField["Cartesian"->"Cylindrical",field,{x,y,z}->{r,θ,\[ScriptZ]}];

getCylindrical/@And[
    x^2+(y-1)^2<=1,
    z<=x^2+y^2,
    z>=0
]
```

> r^2 <= 2 r Sin[θ] && [ScriptZ] <= r^2 && [ScriptZ] >= 0

Now you can use this transformation function to directly specify the conditions in cylindrical coordinates and it will be plotted.

```
With[{
    Δ=0.1
},
    RegionPlot3D[Evaluate[getCartesian/@And[
        r^2<=2r Sin[θ],
        \[ScriptZ]<=r^2,
        \[ScriptZ]>=0
    ]],
        {x,-1-Δ,1+Δ},
        {y,0-Δ,2+Δ},
        {z,0-Δ,4+Δ},

        Mesh->10,
        MeshFunctions->{#3&},
        PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.5],Yellow],
        MeshShading->{Red,Automatic},

        PlotPoints->150,

        PlotTheme->"Detailed",
        AxesLabel->Automatic
    ]
]
```

Comment: Brother how can I learn mathematica, any suggestion about books, videos etc. I really want to learn, but I have no Idea

Comment: @NoorAslam best book for beginners: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat

Comment: Sir the book you recommended is difficult, can you recommend any other book please!

Comment: @NoorAslam https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/

Answer (score 6):

Transform your conditions to cylindrical coordinates

```
cond = 
  x^2 + (y - 1)^2 < 1 &&0 < z < x^2 + y^2 /. {x -> r Cos[φ], y -> r Sin[φ]} // 
    FullSimplify[#, {r > 0, -Pi < φ < Pi}] &

(*r < 2 Sin[φ] && 0 < z < r^2*)
```

to get the integration limits!

The first condition (remember `r > 0`) implies `0 < φ < Pi`.

The integration limits follow to

```
{φ, 0, Pi}, {r, 0, 2 Sin[φ]}, {z, 0, r^2}
```

Checking the results:

Volume of the cartesian region:

```
ImplicitRegion[x^2 + (y - 1)^2 < 1 && 0 < z < x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z}] // Volume

(*3Pi/2*)
```

equals

```
Integrate[r, {φ, 0, Pi}, {r, 0, 2 Sin[φ]}, {z, 0,r^2}]

(* 3Pi/2*)
```

That's it. Hope it helps.