# Using :> vs -> in SequenceReplace

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, sequence

The first example on the page for `SequenceReplace` is the following:

`SequenceReplace[{a, b, x, x, a, c}, {a, e_} :> e]`

`(*b,x,x,c*)`

Why do they use `RuleDelayed` here, instead of `->`? I tried it with `->` and got the same answer.

Comment: In general, when working with patterns, it's just safer. For `->`, `e` is only bound by `e_` if it is present in the rhs *after* evaluation. So for example, `e = 1; SequenceReplace[{a, b, x, x, a, c}, {a, e_} -> e]` gets you `{1, x, x, 1}`. So it's good practice to use `:>` just in case `e` is defined somewhere else, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I remember this was asked before, but can't find it now. i.e. when to use `:>` vs `->`.   As @thorimur mentions, it is related to when right side is evaluated.

If you have Wagner book, look at page 148, he gives a nice example showing when to use and what problem it can cause if you use `->` instead of `:>`

[image]
[image]

This book is now free to download. Thanks to this post [Are you interested in purchasing David Wagner's "Power programming with Mathematica"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat)

[image]