# Speed up the integration of HeavisideTheta over the range from zero to infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, heavisidetheta, diracdelta

The problem is described in the following figure. Mathematica version 14.0, OS windows 10 LTSC.

The integration interval is [0,infinity), and the value of *HeavisideTheta* in the point 0 is 0. we can see, getting the result r1 of expression 1 took time 0.0097771, but **the time consumed in the expression 2 is 0.02, almost the twice of expression 1**. Why is this strange situation happening?

In order to reduce the integrating time, the expression 1 is always used instead of expression 2, because they can provide the same result. However, the integration interval in real physical scenes is [0,infinity).

Based on the book, [Power programming with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat), Changing the lower limit of integration from 0 to 0.0 should improve the integrate performance. In fact, the time was reduced as the expression 3 which gave the result r3 consuming time 0.012, but **the result is not one we want**, because the result is 0 when *HeavisideTheta[0.0] = 0*. How to revise the expression 3?

Can you provide a solution? thank you.

The codes in the case as the following

```
Integrate[
  D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
Integrate[
  D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0, Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
Integrate[
  D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0., Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: which version are you using? on  V 14  on windows 10., I do not see this. Timing is very close. Here is screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Diel.png) also you should really be using `RepeatedTiming`

Comment: These integrals make no sense in traditional math (for example, see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function)).

Comment: @Nasser,Thanks for your response. 1. You run these codes, maybe get a new consuming time near the time in my figure. 2. the lower limit of integration from 0 to 0.0 gives a result not we want, how to deal with it?

Comment: @user64494, Thanks for your answer. When we solve the question in a half space, the stress on the surface of a body is 0, the situation will appear. The snippet codes are parts of my full program. Can you give a solution to deal with the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @likehust For your application it is completely sufficient to assume symmtrical diracdelta, in which case we have `HeavisideTheta[0]==1/2`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, Thanks. 1. We need the HeavisideTheta[0]=0 when defining the boundary condition; 2. DiracDelta faces the same problems of consuming too much time in [0,infinity), and giving fault result at the point z=0.0.

Comment: @likehust Please give an idea of the boundary condition you try to solve.

Comment: @likehust: Can you provide an example when the time of evaluation really matters? Because it the case of examples you provided it does not really matter whether it takes `0.01` seconds or `0.02` seconds.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, Please refer to the website: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0165212587900448

Comment: @azerbajdzan, Thanks. The integration as described is a very small part. If all the elements of a big matrix are similar to it or more complex than it, or the integration is in a big For function, the time of evaluation will really matter.

Comment: @likehust: So then use a replacement `HeavisideTheta[0.] -> 1.` on the output and you get what you want for `Integrate[D[HeavisideTheta[z], z], {z, 0., Infinity}]`.