# Any updates to Withoff’s tutorial?

Tags: reference-request

I was reading ["Power programming with Mathematica" by David Wagner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/27951) and he cites [Withoff’s tutorial](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4683/) for the kernel evaluation process. Is there an updated version of that?