# Applying several functions to the same argument

Tags: function-construction, operators

Is there a more concise way of achieving the following result (possibly without `d |->`)?

```
(d |-> (d@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &)) /@ {f1, f2}
```

---

```
{f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &, 
 f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &}
```

I tried to use `Through` but this gives me incorrect result - the `&` is in the wrong place in the output.

```
Through[{f1, f2}[Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &]]
```

---

```
{f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]] &], 
 f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]] &]}
```

Comment: I think there might a new function in 14.0 that is relevant?

Comment: @mikado: What function? I have version 13.0.

Comment: @mikado is probably referring to [`Comap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Comap.html).

Comment: @Domen: Does `Comap[{f1, f2}, Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &]` output the requested output in 14.0.?

Comment: [Yes, it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx2e7.jpg).

Comment: @Domen I don't think it does. The `f1`/`f2` need to go inside the body of the function.

Comment: `Comap` is experimental in version 14.  Its behavior may change in future versions.

Comment: I can't think of a way to make it more concise than the exhibited `d |->` form, but we can dodge any potential issues with a named function argument using `MapAt[#, Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &, 1]& /@ {f1, f2}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

Longhand

```
Composition[#, Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &] & /@ {f1, f2}
```

Shorthand

```
#@*(Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &) & /@ {f1, f2}
```

Both give

> ```
> {f1@*(Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]] &), 
>  f2@*(Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]] &)}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is the only code in this thread that is shorter than mine. Although the output is not exactly the same it is equivalent to the requested from.

Comment: +1.  It may not matter for the present context, but note that there are subtle evaluation differences between the two forms which might be important when working with symbolic expressions.  e.g. `((d |-> (d[g[#]] &))@Hold)[x]` vs `(#@*(g[#] &) & @ Hold)[x]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Table[{Exponent[#, Variables[expr]]} & /. List -> f, {f, {f1, f2}}]

(* {f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &, 
 f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &} *)
```

Comment: No need for the `ReplaceAll` indirection. Just do `Table[f@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &, {f, {f1, f2}}]`

Comment: @lericr: Wrong result. Who could upvote a comment without even checking it provides a correct result?

Comment: @lericr That results in `{f[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &,  f[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &}` - I don't fully understand why it doesn't work though.

Comment: Yep, my bad. That always happens when I try to reply without having MMA in front of me. It's the `HoldAll` attribute that causes the problem, I think.

Comment: @lericr Seems right, since this also works: `ReleaseHold@ Table[Evaluate@f@Hold@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &, {f, {f1, f2}}]`

Answer (score 4):

If you literally just want shorter, you can just use a different version of `Function`:

```
#@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] & & /@ {f1, f2}
```

Comment: Again, the `&` is not at the position as requested. It is easy to overlook. `]] &]` instead of `]] ]&`.

Comment: dang it. I've updated. I thought the parens would make no difference so added for clarity, and then just visually overlooked the discrepancy.

Comment: Actually, it does work with parens if you do it this way: `(#@Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &) & /@ {f1, f2}`. It's early and maybe I need more coffee, but I'm not really sure why this way works but my original doesn't.

Comment: Yes, now it is correct.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. I see what was wrong with the parens now. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

A dirty alternative:

```
ComapApplyPureFunction[funcs_?VectorQ, pf_Function] := Module[{strpf},
strpf = StringDelete[ToString[pf], "&"];
ToExpression[#1 <> #2 & @@@ 
Thread[{ToString@#2@#1 & @@@ Thread[{strpf, ToString /@ funcs}], 
Array["&" &, Length@funcs]}]]]
```

Testing `ComapApplyPureFunction`:

```
ComapApplyPureFunction[{f1, f2}, Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &]

(*{f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &, f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &}*)
```

**Addendum**:

Perhaps using `Function` instead of an anonymous function will allow you to implement what you are looking for in a more concise way. The following example can be useful:

```
expr = x^2 + 2  x + 1;

With[{f1 = #^2 &, f2 = #^3 &}, ReleaseHold@#2@#1 & @@@ 
Thread[{HoldForm[Function[x, Exponent[x, Variables[x]]]@expr], {f1, f2}}]]

(*{{4}, {8}}*)
```

Comment: These are all the wrong ones :-)

Comment: @azerbajdzan See the update, please! :-)

Comment: Nice, but is in no way more concise (I mean with the definition of `ComapApplyPureFunction`). Anyway (+1).

Answer (score 3):

I think that in Version 14, you would be able to write

```
fn = Comap[{f1, f2}]@*(Exponent[#, Variables[expr]] &)
```

With this definition, you would the have

```
expr = a + b + c
(* a + b + c *)

fn[expr]
(* Comap[{f1, f2}][{1, 1, 1}] *)
```

which I think would be what you wanted (if `Comap` were defined).

I haven't tested this, as I haven't installed version 14 yet.

Comment: `Comap` is experimental in version 14. Its behavior may change in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

Although not more concise, it might be worth noting (as pointed out by [Wagner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485/106), p196) that a pure function may be made listable using `Function[]` syntax (but not, as far as I am aware, with either  `#-&` or  `d |->` syntax).

```
{f1, f2} // Function[x, x[Exponent[#, Variables[expr]]] &, Listable]

(* {f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &, f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &} *)
```

The following will also work:

```
myfn = Function[x, (x[Exponent[#, Variables[expr]]] &), Listable];

myfn[{f1, f2}]

(* {f1[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &, f2[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] &} *)
```

But (as again pointed out by Wagner), the following won't, as the listable attribute is 'stripped off' when `fn` is replaced by its ownvalue during evaluation:

```
fn = Function[x, (x[Exponent[#, Variables[expr]]] &)];
SetAttributes[fn, Listable]
fn[{f1, f2}]

(* {f1, f2}[Exponent[#1, Variables[expr]]] & *)
```